# How to deal with SQL column names that look like SQL keywords?

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my columns is called `from`. I can't change the name because I didn't make it.
Am I allowed to do something like `SELECT from FROM TableName` or is there a special syntax to avoid the SQL Server being confused?

Comment: I'd say use ANSI SQL's double quotes for delimited identifiers. It will work on almost any dbms, including SQL Server. I.e. simply do `SELECT "from" FROM TableName`, nice and portable!

Answer (score 443, accepted):

Wrap the column name in brackets like so, `from` becomes [from].

```
select [from] from table;
```

It is also possible to use the following (useful when querying multiple tables):

```
select table.[from] from table;
```

Comment: What about:
`select TableName.from from TableName;`   
PS: It works in MySQL

Comment: I tried this just this morning, and it didn't seem to work in my MySQL installation.  Is it a parameter or something that turns it on?

Comment: @CodeChimp - try using backticks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names  This question/answer is specific to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Right, but @FabricioPH mentioned it working in MySQL.  I happened across here from a Google search after I tried this on my local MySQL install.  I was looking to see if there was a generic ANSI SQL way of escaping stuff like this in SQL.  We are currently using SQL Server 2005, but we also have Oracle in some of our other apps.  We would like to code our Java DAOs in such a way that if we were ever told to move from SQL Server to something else, it would just "work".

Comment: @CodeChimp I can count the number of times that's happened to me on no fingers. :)

Comment: @FabricioPH Your solution of writing `tablename.columnname` without the square brackets does not appear to work on SQL Server 2017. Using the square brackets, however, does work.

Comment: In general you'll need brackets around any column names which are the same as SQL Server commands, such as `TableName.[from]`, Israel

Answer (score 38):

If it had been in PostgreSQL, use double quotes around the name, like:

```
select "from" from "table";
```

Note: Internally PostgreSQL automatically converts all unquoted commands and parameters to lower case. That have the effect that commands and identifiers aren't case sensitive. **sEleCt * from tAblE;** is interpreted as **select * from table;**. However, parameters inside double quotes are used as is, and therefore ARE case sensitive: **select * from "table";** and **select * from "Table";** gets the result from two different tables.

Comment: The double quotes work for MS SQL, too, without the case sensitivity, though.  Quoted identifiers are just, AFAIK, an equivalent alternative to bracket-delimited identifiers.

Comment: Double quotes also works for the Presto SQL query engine as used by Amazon's Athena.

Answer (score 27):

These are the two ways to do it:

1. Use back quote as here:

> SELECT `from` FROM TableName

2. You can mention with table name as:

> `SELECT TableName.from FROM TableName`

Comment: Thanks, the double quote and square brackets syntax didn't work with my client (MySQLWorkbench) but the back tick method did.

Answer (score 22):

While you are doing it - alias it as something else (or better yet, use a view or an SP and deprecate the old direct access method).

```
SELECT [from] AS TransferFrom -- Or something else more suitable
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 12):

Your question seems to be well answered here, but I just want to add one more comment to this subject.

Those designing the database should be well aware of the reserved keywords and avoid using them.  If you discover someone using it, inform them about it (in a polite way).  The keyword here is *reserved* word.

More information:

> "Reserved keywords should not be used
>   as object names. Databases upgraded
>   from earlier versions of SQL Server
>   may contain identifiers that include
>   words not reserved in the earlier
>   version, but that are reserved words
>   for the current version of SQL Server.
>   You can refer to the object by using
>   delimited identifiers until the name
>   can be changed."
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx

and

> "If your database does contain names
>   that match reserved keywords, you must
>   use delimited identifiers when you
>   refer to those objects. For more
>   information, see Identifiers (DMX)."
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132178.aspx

Answer (score 9):

In Apache Drill, use backquotes:

```
select `from` from table;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you ARE using SQL Server, you can just simply wrap the square brackets around the column or table name.

```
select [select]
from [table]
```

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced this issue. 
And the solution for this is to put [Column_Name] like this in the query.

```
string query= "Select [Name],[Email] from Person";
```

So it will work perfectly well.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I work on Teradata systems that is completely ANSI compliant. Use double quotes " " to name such columns.

E.g. `type` is a SQL reserved keyword, and when used within quotes, `type` is treated as a user specified name.

See below code example:

```
CREATE TABLE alpha1
AS
(
SEL
product1
type_of_product AS "type"
FROM beta1
) WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (product1)

--type is a SQL reserved keyword

TYPE

--see? now to retrieve the column you would use:

SEL "type" FROM alpha1
```

Comment: I confirm this works in DBeaver with Teradata database, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution

Lets say the column name is **from** ; So the column name in query can be referred by table alias

```
Select * from user u where u.from="US"
```

Answer (score 3):

Some solid answers—but the most-upvoted one is parochial, only dealing with SQL Server. In summary:

- If you have source control, the best solution is to stick to the rules, and avoid using reserved words. [This list](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) has been around for ages, and covers most of the peculiarities. One tip is that reserved words are rarely plural—so you're usually safe using plural names. Exceptions are  DIAGNOSTICS, SCHEMAS, OCTETS, OFFSETS, OPTIONS, VALUES, PARAMETERS, PRIVILEGES and also verb-like words that also appear plural: OVERLAPS, READS, RETURNS,  TRANSFORMS.
- Many of us don't have the luxury of changing the field names. There, you'll need to know the details of the RDBM you're accessing:
- For *SQL Server* use [square_braces] around the name. This works in an ODBC connection too.
- For *MySQL* use `back_ticks`.
- Postgres, Oracle and several other RDBMs will apparently allow "double_quotes" to be used.

Dotting the offending word onto the table name may also work.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in the same issue when trying to **update** a column which name was a **keyword**. The solution above didn't help me. I solved it out by simply specifying the name of the table like this:

```
UPDATE `survey`
SET survey.values='yes,no'
WHERE (question='Did you agree?')
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will work perfectly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table.from AS a FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your column name in bracket like:

```
Select  [from] from < ur_tablename>
```

Or

Put in a temprary table then use as you like.
Example:

```
Declare @temp_table table(temp_from varchar(max))

Insert into @temp_table
Select * from your_tablename
```

Here I just assume that your_tablename contains only one column (i.e. from).

Comment: That presumes that `[from]` is the only column that `your_tablename` has got.

Comment: What do you gain from the temporary table? It seems completely useless, nothing to do with the question at all.

Comment: @rjmunro, no, this does not seem completely useless. I have a case where I query a tabular cube from SQL and it returns names of columns like '[Total].' That is, the name itself contains '[' and ']'. You can't use [[Total]] and [Total] to retrieve such a column. The easiest way is to put the result of the query into a temp table.

Comment: @darlove Can't you use quotes: `"[Total]"`? Or maybe there is a way to escape it, something like `[\[Total\]]`?

Comment: @rjmunro, after having experimented with this a bit I've found another way about which I didn't know: you can set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to ON and then use what you're talking about, the double quote ". So, it's just another way but I wouldn't discard the temp table option completely.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, alternatively to using back quotes (`), you can use the UI to alter column names. Right click the table > Alter table > Edit the column name that contains sql keyword > Commit.

```
select [from] from <table>
```

As a note, the above does not work in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the answers here and my own experience. The only acceptable answer, if you're planning on being portable is don't use SQL keywords for table, column, or other names.

All these answers work in the various databases but apparently a lot don't support the ANSI solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28948340)

Comment: @TanmayNehete My answer there isn't any link. Either you commented on the wrong answer, or chose the wrong explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL Developer, pl/sql you can do this with double quotes but if you use double quotes you must type the column names in upper case.  For example, SELECT "FROM" FROM MY_TABLE