# How to map an entity field whose name is a reserved word in JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, orm, jpa

```
@Column(name="open")
```

Using sqlserver dialect with hibernate.

```
[SchemaUpdate] Unsuccessful: create table auth_session (id numeric(19,0) identity not null, active tinyint null, creation_date datetime not null, last_modified datetime not null, maxidle int null, maxlive int null, open tinyint null, sessionid varchar(255) not null, user_id numeric(19,0) not null, primary key (id), unique (sessionid))
[SchemaUpdate] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'open'.
```

I would have expected hibernate to use quoted identifier when creating the table.

Any ideas on how to handle this... other than renaming the field?

Comment: See e.g. https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1272

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Had the same problem, but with a tablename called `Transaction`. If you set

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Then all database identifiers will be quoted.

Found my answer here
[Special character in table name hibernate giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065136/special-character-in-table-name-hibernate-giving-error)

And found all available settings here
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html

Could not find better docs for this though.

In my case the setting was in my Spring properties file. As mentioned in the comments, it could also be in other, hibernate related, configuration files.

Comment: How is this not the default setting?

Comment: SQL might become unreadable and using keywords as names is a bad practice that should not be encouraged. I think...?

Comment: Okay. I'll prefer an escaped reserved word as a name all day long over a name that doesn't fit.

Comment: Yes, you could say that the abstraction provided by Hibernate is only of concern and not how it is technically implemented. But if you also use tooling like Flyway or Liquibase, then it adds to complexity when you need to consider that there might be reserved words. This has been my experience when migrating schema's.

Comment: For those wondering where this needs to be set, it's probably in your `persistence.xml` for JBoss projects.

Comment: Using Spring: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`

Answer (score 159):

With Hibernate as JPA 1.0 provider, you can escape a reserved keyword by enclosing it within backticks:

```
@Column(name="`open`")
```

This is the syntax inherited from Hibernate Core:

> #### [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)
>
> You can force Hibernate to quote an
> identifier in the generated SQL by
> enclosing the table or column name in
> backticks in the mapping document.
> Hibernate will use the correct
> quotation style for the SQL Dialect.
> This is usually double quotes, but the
> SQL Server uses brackets and MySQL
> uses backticks.
>
> ```
> <class name="LineItem" table="`Line Item`">
>     <id name="id" column="`Item Id`"/><generator class="assigned"/></id>
>     <property name="itemNumber" column="`Item #`"/>
>     ...
> </class>
> ```

In JPA 2.0, the syntax is standardized and becomes:

```
@Column(name="\"open\"")
```

#### References

- Hibernate reference guide
- [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)
- JPA 2.0 specification
- 2.13 Naming of Database Objects

#### Related questions

- [Hibernate, MySQL and table named “Repeat” - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217479/hibernate-mysql-and-table-named-repeat-strange-behaviour)
- [Automatic reserved word escaping for Hibernate tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns)

Comment: And thanks from me. It solved a problem I had. btw - Ref is now at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers

Comment: I don't understand why I have to do this, why Hibernate don't do this automatically instead of me???

Comment: @DanielHári maybe you find my answer more "automatic"?

Comment: Using `@Column(name="[open]")` is much prettier :)

Comment: If you use _@Column(name="\"open\"")_ on **Oracle**, note that quoted identifiers are case sensitive. Which means most likely you need to use **@Column(name="\"OPEN\"")** instead, otherwise you'll get an invalid identifier error.

Answer (score 30):

### Manually escaping the reserved keywords

If you are using JPA, you can escape with double quotes:

```
@Column(name = "\"open\"")
```

If you're using Hibernate native API, then you can escape them using backticks:

```
@Column(name = "`open`")
```

### Automatically escaping reserved keywords

If you want to automatically escape reserved keywords, you can set to `true` the Hibernate-specific [`hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`](https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/) configuration property:

```xml
<property
    name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"
    value="true"
/>
```

**Yaml format**

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
```

Answer (score 17):

If you use as shown below it should work

```
@Column(name="[order]")
private int order;
```

Comment: You're just doing this on the private field not on the getter?

Comment: this is sqlserver specific.

Answer (score 13):

```
@Column(name="\"open\"")
```

This will work for sure, Same problem happened with me, when I was learning hibernate.

Answer (score 12):

There is also another option: [hibernate.auto_quote_keyword](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_quoting_options)

which

> Specifies whether to automatically quote any names that are deemed keywords.

```xml
<property name="hibernate.auto_quote_keyword" value="true" />
```

Yaml

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        auto_quote_keyword: true
```

Comment: I found this better than globally_quoted_identifiers because this only quotes reserved keywords instead of every identifier.

Comment: It's a shame this isn't set by default, I can see that not setting this makes it harder to switch to another JPA implementation that doesn't support automatic quoting.

Answer (score 3):

No - change the column name.

This is database-specific, and you just can't create such a column. After all hibernate finally sends DDL to the database. If you can't create a valid DDL with this column name, this means hibernate can't as well. I don't think quoting would solve the issue even if you are writing the DDL.

Even if you somehow succeed to escape the name - change it. It will work with this database, but won't work with another.

Comment: That *may* work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords. Let's wait for the OP confirmation.

Comment: This is not database-specific! You escape it with a ` and hibernate translate it to correct quotation style for the SQL Dialect

Answer (score 3):

Some JPA implementations (e.g the one I use, DataNucleus) automatically quote the identifier for you, so you never get this.

Comment: Yes, surprised that Hibernate seemingly still does not offer such a basic feature given the number of times people get hit by it (and someone even downvoted you for daring to mention that this was possible elsewhere)