# Automatic reserved word escaping for Hibernate tables and columns

Tags: java, hibernate, escaping, orm, reserved-words

I am trying to use one Hibernate mapping for several different databases: H2, Oracle, MySql.

Each database has a different list of reserved words.

I would like Hibernate to automatically escape the reserved words.

I know I can:

- use backticks to force escaping (escape everything just to be safe)
- change all identifiers so they are certainly not keywords in any database (make them ugly)
- tie the schema to a specific set of databases, escaping the union of keywords (will break if I add new database to the mix)

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: In my opinion this is an omission in hibernate, and the severity of the omission is tantamount to it being a bug.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

AFAIK, Hibernate doesn't maintain a list of reserved keyword (per database) so I think you should look at database identifier escaping.

If you are using Hibernate 3.5+, try `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` to quote all database identifiers (this is something they added for JPA 2.0, see the secion **2.13 Naming of Database Objects** of the spec for the JPA way to activate this if you are using JPA).

Prior to version 3.5, Hibernate doesn't offer any configuration option for global escaping. Implementing a custom `NamingStrategy` to escape everything transparently would be the recommended way.

#### See also

- [Database independant Column/Table name escaping?](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=970380&view=next)
- [HHH-2578 - redesign SessionFactory building](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2578) - my understanding is that fixing this issue would make automatic escaping of keywords (through dialects) possible.

Comment: Thank you. I am quite puzzled that this is not a default setting, considering that lack of escaping can only cause you a headache, and there is nothing positive to it... hmm, maybe case insensitivity.

Comment: @Roman I guess there must be a *good* reason (I hope so) but I don't know it (maybe case insensitivity indeed).

Answer (score 1):

We are using Oracle and H2 and I stumbled upon a similar issue.

I tried the Hibernate option `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true` but Oracle did not digest it well, raising an `ORA-00904` on all quoted column names.

Adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` on top of the above made it work (cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/48113507/19623995)