# Unable to use table named "user" in postgresql hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

When I try to persist an entity called "user" with JPA/hibernate it does not work. The table is not created and it is because user is a reserved word in postgresql. Is there any way other than naming the table something else to make this work?

Comment: I just ran into this, I thought switchign db vendor with hibernate was  supposed to be problem free

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/q/3364835/1266906 you can use hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true in recent versions of hibernate

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To quote an identifier, use back ticks:

```
@Table(name="`users`")
```

See this example from Hibernate's test suite:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/quote/User.java#L31

Hibernate will automatically detect it and convert to the appropriate quote for the database you are using.

Comment: Changed. But one could infer the location by reading the URL, no?

Answer (score 20):

JPA supports the following syntax for specifying that the tablename must be used exactly as specified:

```
@Table(name="\"user\"")
```

Try using this annotation on your entity class and see if it does the trick. The backslashes are used to escape one set of double-quotes, so it looks kind of ugly.

Comment: Cool, that worked for the table - but the next problem is that tables like user_user_permissions (a collection field in the User class called userPermissions) that gets the same problem for some reason. The reason why I can not set the table name for that field is because it is in a parent class because this is a common field for most of my classes. Any ideas?

Comment: Piotr, user_user_permissions should be fine as a table name, what error are you getting? Is one of your columns called "user"? (AFAIK wanting to map the same thing different ways is incompatible with annotations though)

Comment: This causes failed POST requests when using a Spring PagingAndSortingRepository of user entity. I'm using postgres.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that you should avoid having table names that are reserved words, with hibernate. Sure you can escape it, but it may cause problems in the future (in a query for example). So the safest way is to name the table another way - say `users`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {..}
```

Comment: Not sure I agree. Hibernate is pretty capable of quoting wherever needed. If it doesn't, then it's a bug and should be reported.

Comment: I agree, you may need to access the database from a non-ORM domain in future, so it is better to avoid using those keywords.

Answer (score 6):

As others said, `user` is a reserved word in SQL and Postgres.

Many databases have many reserved words, over a thousand the last time I tallied. So it is very easy to run into weird problem due to a reserved word collision.

## Trailing underscore: `user_`

Here is the handiest tip I ever learned for SQL: Always **append a trailing underscore** to your names. I do this for table names, column names, index names, and so on.

The SQL spec specifically promises<sup>†</sup> to never have a keyword or reserved word with a trailing underscore. This promise is oddly inserted into the spec with no context. But to me it screams out “Append underscore to all your names!”.

After adopting this rule, I discovered a pleasant secondary benefit. When I see the underscore in the code, in the comments, in issue-tracking, and in the emails, I always know we are referring specifically to the database item such as `customer_` table versus the concept of “customer” or the class `Customer` in my Java code.

---

<sup>†</sup> I cannot quote the SQL spec because it is copyright protected, unfortunately. In the [*SQL:2011*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) spec, read section 5.4 *Names and identifiers* under the heading *Syntax Rules* item 3, NOTE 111. In [*SQL-92*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) see section 5.2, item 11. Just searching for the word `underscore` will work.

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL follows the ANSI standard for quoting object names, so you need to specify "user" as the tablename (including the double quotes)

```
SELECT *
FROM "user";
```

I don't know how you would tell hibernate to generate such a statement.

I strongly recommend you find a different name for your table, it will give you more problems that it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use schema name to refer to the user table. Use default public schema if you aren't using any specific one.

```
@Table(name="user", schema="public")
```