# ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using Hibernate and have a persistent class called "User". Since this is a keyword, I marked the @Entity attribute with a different name (I have seen, for example, this question:
[Unable to use table named "user" in postgresql hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350874/unable-to-use-table-named-user-in-postgresql-hibernate))

However, I still run into trouble because this class extends another, and it looks like hibernate is still trying to use "user" as a column name and getting messed up:

```
@Entity( name = "XonamiUser" )
public class User extends PropertyContainer {
    ...
```

and

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PropertyContainer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected long key;
    /** tags */
    @ElementCollection
    protected Set<String> tags;

    @ElementCollection
    protected Set<String> searchList;
    ...
```

My other classes that extend PropertyContainer seem to work fine.

Is this a bug in hibernate? Is there some way around this short of refactoring? Thanks!

Here are the errors I'm seeing (slightly cleaned up):

```
WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 insert into user_search_list (user, search_list) values ('1', 'bjorn') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 31
```

Comment: @TJ, I added the errors which lead me to believe it's still using the column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I refactored the class user to XonamiUser. This wasn't quite what I wanted, but it worked great.

Answer (score 78):

`user` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in PostgreSQL. It is allowed only as [quoted identifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

You have to force Hibernate to use quoted `"user"` in this INSERT command.

I'm not Hibernate expert but maybe this [Hibernate saving User model to Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608420/hibernate-saving-user-model-to-postgres) will help?

Comment: yes, the question I linked to in my original post makes the same point. This is the reason I used the @Entity( name = "XonamiUser" ) annotation.

Comment: My error was sth like ERROR: syntax error at or near. Hibernate overwrites the actual error of Postgresql for reserved word. It took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: @BjornRoche I think the question is similar to your's question.. could you pls help me on this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224949/exception-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-syntax-error-at-or-near-c?noredirect=1#comment71610583_42224949

Comment: I had this issue inside entity fixed by `@column(name="\"user\"")`

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit confused are you referring to a column or table named User... You can use the [@Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html)-annotation to set the table name for the entity in JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XonamiUser")
public class User extends PropertyContainer {
```

Comment: I get "Unsuccessful: create table user_search_list (user int8 not null, search_list varchar(255))... ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"

Answer (score 1):

The [Hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-ofvalues) has an exemple showing how to define the table name used to hold the elements of the collection. And it happens to use a User entity to do so, and to define the column as `user_id` rather than user.

This mapping should be OK, for your case:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "user_search_list", 
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "search_list")
protected Set<String> searchList;
```

Comment: This assumes that User is the only class that subclasses PropertyContainer, doesn't it?

Comment: No. Hibernate names the join column "user" because it joins to an entity named "User".

Comment: but searchList belongs to PropertyContainer, so User, and other classes inherit it. If I tell hibernate that it should use the name user_search_list, then won't it try to use that name for all classes that inherit?