# Exception : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "call"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgresql-9.4

I am working on a application in which hibernate  and postgresql and giving the following error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "call"

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong. I am using Postgres 9.4.

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value


    type Exception report

    message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception 
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



    root cause 
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
        org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
        org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)

    ...

    root cause 
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "call"
      Position: 1
        org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
        org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
        org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
        org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
        org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
        org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:75)
        org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:58)
        org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:99)
        org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
        org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
        org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:94)
        org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
        org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
        org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
        org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
        com.dineshonjava.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:22)
        com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:26)
```

**EmployeeController**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.techprep.bean.EmployeeBean;
import com.techprep.model.Employee;
import com.techprep.service.EmpService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmpService empService;


     @RequestMapping("/addEmployee")
     public ModelAndView showForm(){
           // return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee","emp",new EmployeeBean());  
     }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("emp")EmployeeBean employeeBean, 
               BindingResult result) {
              Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
              empService.addEmployee(employee);
              return new ModelAndView("success");
             }

    @RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
      Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(empService.listEmployeess()));
      return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
     }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")EmployeeBean employeeBean,
       BindingResult result) {
        empService.deleteEmployee(prepareModel(employeeBean));
      Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      model.put("employee", null);
      model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(empService.listEmployeess()));
      return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
     }

    private Employee prepareModel(EmployeeBean employeeBean){
          Employee employee = new Employee();
          employee.setEmpAddress(employeeBean.getAddress());
          employee.setEmpAge(employeeBean.getAge());
          employee.setEmpName(employeeBean.getName());
          employee.setSalary(employeeBean.getSalary());
          employee.setEmpId(employeeBean.getId());
          employeeBean.setId(null);
          return employee;
         }

    private List<EmployeeBean> prepareListofBean(List<Employee> employees){
          List<EmployeeBean> beans = null;
          if(employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()){
           beans = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
           EmployeeBean bean = null;
           for(Employee employee : employees){
            bean = new EmployeeBean();
            bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
            bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
            bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
            bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
            bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
            beans.add(bean);
           }
          }
          return beans;
         }

    @RequestMapping(value="/show")
    public String show(){
        return "show";
    }

}
```

**Employee.java Class**

```
  import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
    import javax.persistence.Table;





    @Entity
    @Table(name="Employee")
    public class Employee {
         @Id
         @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="empsequence")
         @SequenceGenerator(name ="empsequence", sequenceName="empsequence")
         @Column(name = "empid")
         private Integer empId;

         @Column(name="empname")
         private String empName;

         @Column(name="empaddress")
         private String empAddress;

         @Column(name="salary")
         private Long salary;

         @Column(name="empAge")
         private Integer empAge;

        public Integer getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }

        public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }

        public String getEmpName() {
            return empName;
        }

        public void setEmpName(String empName) {
            this.empName = empName;
        }

        public String getEmpAddress() {
            return empAddress;
        }

        public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
            this.empAddress = empAddress;
        }

        public Long getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary(Long salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public Integer getEmpAge() {
            return empAge;
        }

        public void setEmpAge(Integer empAge) {
            this.empAge = empAge;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to show your code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe code added

Comment: At which line in the code is the exception thrown?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe when we try to enter the data in postgresql through the form ... it will show the exception org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "call"

Comment: Are you sure you set up the correct hibernate dialect? (It's the `databasePlatform` property of `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` if you use that -- or the `database` (enum) property, but that sets a deprecated dialect for PostgreSQL).

Comment: I was using a wrong dailect ... by using the dailect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect with postgres 9.4 the application is running properly ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a wrong dailect earlier by using the dailect **org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect** with **postgres 9.4** the application is running properly

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem and it turns out it is indeed due to the use of incompatible SQLDialect.
For me since I am using postgres 10.5 using `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect` solved the problem.