# Hibernate: weird exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

**Problem:** I've a simple entity with id property, and I can't save it.

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at ...
```

**Code:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;

    //getter & setter

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = new User();
        session.persist(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**HQL:**

```
Hibernate: create table User (userId int8 not null, primary key (userId))
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into User (userId) values (?)
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
  Position: 13
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: also, "User" is a reserved keyword, try naming the table "user_table" or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User is a reserved Keyword in many Databases.

You should not name your table like this.

Try:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyUser")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the *User* as a table name, you could write:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`User`")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;
```

or if you use JPA 2.0, you can also escape like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"User\"")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;
```

The most safe way though is that you should use a non-reserved word as table name, as @Angelo wrote.
Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350874/unable-to-use-table-named-user-in-postgresql-hibernate) for more details