# Hibernate and postgresql. Errors while exporting schema

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I'm getting around 10 errors when I start my Spring Boot app using Hibernate and postgresql. How can I fix them? WHat's the problem?
Here are my entities:

**Customer.java**

```
   @Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD) // so I can avoid using setters for fields that won't change
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long customerId;

  @Embedded
  private FirstName firstName;
  @Embedded
  private LastName lastName;
  @Embedded
  private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
  private Address address;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private User user;

  // jpa requirement
  public Customer() {
  }

  public Customer(FirstName firstName, LastName lastName,
      PhoneNumber phoneNumber, Address address, User user) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.address = address;
    this.user = user;
  }

  public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }

  public FirstName getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public LastName getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
  }

  // setter for phone number is needed because customer can change his phone number
  public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  // setter for address is needed because customer can change his address
  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }

    Customer customer = (Customer) o;

    if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(customer.firstName) : customer.firstName != null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(customer.lastName) : customer.lastName != null) {
      return false;
    }
    return user != null ? user.equals(customer.user) : customer.user == null;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (user != null ? user.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Customer{" +
        "firstName=" + firstName +
        ", lastName=" + lastName +
        ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber +
        '}';
  }
}
```

**User.java**

```
   @Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long userId;

  @Embedded
  private EmailAddress emailAddress;
  @Embedded
  private Password password;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
  private Customer customer;

  @Column
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private UserRole userRole;

  // jpa requirement
  public User() {
  }

  public User(EmailAddress emailAddress, Password password) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.password = password;
    this.userRole = UserRole.USER; // on creation everyone is just a user
  }

  public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }

  public EmailAddress getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
  }

  public void setEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
  }

  public Password getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(Password password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
  }

  public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  public UserRole getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
  }

  public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
  }
}
```

And **Book.java**:

```
    @Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD) // so I can avoid using setters for fields that won't change
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long bookId;

  @Embedded
  private Isbn isbn;
  @Embedded
  private Title title;
  @Embedded
  private Author author;
  @Embedded
  private Genre genre;
  private Year publicationYear;
  private BigDecimal price;

  // jpa requirement
  public Book() {
  }

  public Book(Isbn isbn, Title title, Author author, Genre genre, Year publicationYear,
      BigDecimal price) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public Long getBookId() {
    return bookId;
  }

  public Isbn getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
  }

  public Title getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public Genre getGenre() {
    return genre;
  }

  public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public Year getPublicationYear() {
    return publicationYear;
  }

  // setter for price is needed because price of the book can change (discounts and so on)
  public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

}
```

My application.properties for postgresql settings:

```
    spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bookrest
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

And here is the stack trace for hibernate part (ommitted all the controoller mapping):

```
    2017-02-27 11:03:05.481  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-02-27 11:03:05.555  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-02-27 11:03:05.556  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-02-27 11:03:05.558  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-02-27 11:03:05.609  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-02-27 11:03:05.819  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2017-02-27 11:03:05.997  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-02-27 11:03:05.999  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@c866efb
2017-02-27 11:03:06.228  WARN 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
2017-02-27 11:03:06.580  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-02-27 11:03:06.584 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table customer drop constraint FKglkhkmh2vyn790ijs6hiqqpi
2017-02-27 11:03:06.584 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "customer" does not exist
2017-02-27 11:03:06.584 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table customer drop constraint FKidmyb2vdwmk3o502u0rg8g32h
2017-02-27 11:03:06.585 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "customer" does not exist
2017-02-27 11:03:06.585 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user drop constraint FK2q989f4c89rv2b9xvtomfc0fs
2017-02-27 11:03:06.586 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 13
2017-02-27 11:03:06.587 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user cascade
2017-02-27 11:03:06.587 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 22
2017-02-27 11:03:06.588 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
2017-02-27 11:03:06.588 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
2017-02-27 11:03:06.607 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table user (user_id  bigserial not null, email_address varchar(255), password varchar(255), user_role varchar(255), customer_customer_id int8, primary key (user_id))
2017-02-27 11:03:06.607 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 14
2017-02-27 11:03:06.610 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table customer add constraint FKidmyb2vdwmk3o502u0rg8g32h foreign key (user_user_id) references user
2017-02-27 11:03:06.610 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 103
2017-02-27 11:03:06.610 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user add constraint FK2q989f4c89rv2b9xvtomfc0fs foreign key (customer_customer_id) references customer
2017-02-27 11:03:06.610 ERROR 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 13
2017-02-27 11:03:06.611  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-02-27 11:03:06.673  INFO 6563 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

EDIT 1:

After changing my User to AppUser (table name user is prohibited) I'm still getting few errors:

```
   2017-02-27 11:45:44.253  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-02-27 11:45:44.255  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-02-27 11:45:44.256  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-02-27 11:45:44.298  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-02-27 11:45:44.621  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2017-02-27 11:45:44.825  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-02-27 11:45:44.828  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@35c0ac4e
2017-02-27 11:45:45.370  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-02-27 11:45:45.373 ERROR 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table app_user drop constraint FKf8cjd2mkc4tu1u5nhju0clae7
2017-02-27 11:45:45.374 ERROR 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "app_user" does not exist
2017-02-27 11:45:45.374 ERROR 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table customer drop constraint FKglkhkmh2vyn790ijs6hiqqpi
2017-02-27 11:45:45.374 ERROR 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "customer" does not exist
2017-02-27 11:45:45.375 ERROR 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table customer drop constraint FKslkyb5dphxe4c7au3hqx3la6m
2017-02-27 11:45:45.375 ERROR 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "customer" does not exist
2017-02-27 11:45:45.408  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-02-27 11:45:45.467  INFO 9560 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959373/hibernate-weird-exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in postgresql. I would suggest renaming your entity class to some other name, or just use [hibernate annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity) `@Table` to specify postgresql friendly table name, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "library_user")
public class User {...}
```

Comment: Changed that but I'm still getting few errors -> posted them in edit 1.

Comment: @doublemc That's probably caused by your `create-drop` policy. Hibernate is trying to drop your old tables, and can't find this new `app_user`. I would suggest to drop all tables and constraints manually and rerun your app.

Comment: The problem was I didn't have a setter for ID in user entity, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

User is reserved word in most if not all of the databases. Use some other name for this purpose.

[Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)