# Why I cannot define an column named "index" in jpa?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I use jpa to persist an object to mysql databse.

When I define a column named "index" like below, the table will not be generated in database.

When I delete it or rename it, the jpa works fine.

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import play.db.jpa.GenericModel;

@Entity
@Table(name="QA_ASSETVM")
public class QAAssetVM extends GenericModel{

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id 
     @Column(name="vmassetname")
     public String vmassetname;

     @Column(name="assetvm_index")  //this works fine!
     public int index;
     /*
     @Column(name="index")  //When I add this, the table "QA_ASSETVM" will not be generated by jpa in database.
     public int index;
     */
}
```

Comment: Can't test here, but can you declare public int index twice?

Comment: `index` and other keywords cannot be used as for column name..

Comment: Obviously they can be used if they are quoted, and that is exactly what some other JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus JPA) do for the user ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried using mysql, but 'index' seems to be a reserved word.

check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) out.

Answer (score 3):

As Hannibal pointed out, `index` is a reserved keyword in MySQL therefore you cannot use it directly as a column name, but you have to escape it.

1. If you are using Hibernate 3.5+, try with `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`, which will quote all database indentifiers (source: [Automatic reserved word escaping for Hibernate tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns#3368289))
2. In JPA 2.0, you can use the annotation: `@Column(name="\"index\"")`, which is the new standardize way to escape a single column

Answer (score 1):

Because index is the reserved word. In order to use index as a column name you have to use write it within []. like this :

```
@Column(name="[index]")
```