# hibernate inserting without left ticks

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do insert using hibernate and am running into an issue. When I use the following code

```
@Override
    public Serializable addTestResult(Result test_result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCurrentSession().save(test_result);
    }
```

the end query looks like this:

```
mysql> insert into test_results (db, host) values ('db1', 'host1');
```

which gets rejected by mysql since there are left tick missing in the column name. How can I have hibernate add quotes around the column name so that the query looks like this:

```
mysql> insert into test_results (`db`, `host`) values ('db1', 'host1');
```

Comment: I don't think that is an invalid statement for mysql. Do you receive a syntax error or any other error?

Comment: @porfiriopartida not until you use MySQL reserved keywords for column names.

Comment: Right.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html I thought it was only to prevent naming issues (like phpmyadmin does) for tables and fields with more than 1 word... interesting.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the table/ column names you need quoted with ` back-ticks in your .hbm.xml or mapping annotations.

For example:

```
<property name='DB" column='`db`' />
@Column(name="`db`")
```

This tells Hibernate to quote these identifiers to the database. I use this, for example, with a `USER` table. As with any app, most table & column-names are not conflicting but `user` tends to be a SQL keyword.

You don't need to switch on quoting globally.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the option `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`.

Source: [Automatic reserved word escaping for Hibernate tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns)