# Receiving Error: 1064 on oneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Following is my DTO object of customer class. When i make some get query on hibernate i receive 1064 error

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name="code")
private String code;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

@Column(name="phone1")
private String phone1;

@Column(name="phone2")
private String phone2;

@Column(name="credit_limit")
private BigDecimal creditLimit;

@Column(name="current_credit")
private BigDecimal currentCredit;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
private Set<Order> orders;}
```

then i call following method

```
public List<Order> allOrders(){
    return orderDao.findAll();
}
```

this is the error i receive.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order orders0_ where orders0_.customer_id=5' at line 1
Hibernate: 
select
    customer0_.id as id1_0_,
    customer0_.address as address2_0_,
    customer0_.code as code3_0_,
    customer0_.credit_limit as credit_l4_0_,
    customer0_.current_credit as current_5_0_,
    customer0_.phone1 as phone6_0_,
    customer0_.phone2 as phone7_0_ 
from
    customer customer0_
Hibernate: 
select
    orders0_.customer_id as customer2_0_0_,
    orders0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    orders0_.id as id1_1_1_,
    orders0_.customer_id as customer2_1_1_ 
from

order orders0_ where
    orders0_.customer_id=?
```

Can you please tell what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: have you added `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>`  to your persistence.xml

Comment: <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="packagesToScan">
   <list>
    <value>com.sales.service.domain</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: the error indicate that you have a mapping error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `Order` entity: `order` is a reserved word in sql. Best is to change the table name to something else, e.g.  `@Table(name = "orders")` - with an `s`.

Alternatively, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns) answer:

> If you are using Hibernate 3.5+, try
>   hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true to quote all database
>   identifiers (this is something they added for JPA 2.0, see the secion
>   2.13 Naming of Database Objects of the spec for the JPA way to activate this if you are using JPA).