# Hibernate: Could not execute Batch Update

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11g

I'm trying to update a single table in my record using the session.getCurrentSession().save(Bean);
And I'm getting this error. I have cross checked my table and column names in my Database with the attributes in my POJO class. The hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property is set to auto in my configuration file. Please help

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/PhoneStore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into MOBILEPHONES_TB (BATTERY, BRAND, COLOR, DISPLAY, MEMORY, MODEL_NAME, OS, PRIMARY_CAMERA, PROCESSOR, RESOLUTION, SCREEN_TYPE, SECONDARY_CAMERA, SIM_SIZE, SIM_TYPE, SIZE, MODEL_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update] with root cause
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10055)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:375)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy29.addPhone(Unknown Source)
    at com.wipro.phonestore.controller.AdminController.addPhone(AdminController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check with a sql tool, that you can execute that statement.

Comment: yaa. I tries to insert using SQL Plus as well as SQL Developer. I'm able to insert the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how that statement could run in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer.

The name of one of your columns "**`SIZE`**" is an Oracle reserved word. It would need to be enclosed in double quotes, in order for it to be referenced in an INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO foo ("SIZE") VALUES ( ? )
                 ^    ^
```

The Oracle error message ORA-1747 is pretty clear about what the problem is.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: I'm using HQL to perform the insert operation. So, how can I achieve the insert operation there?

Comment: You'd need to get Hibernate to properly escape a reserved word when it's used as an identifier (e.g. a column name.) How do you get Hibernate to wrap double quotes around the column name? That question has been asked before, reference: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my column name from Size to Phone_Size and was able to insert the queries. 
Thanks. :)