# JPA - Getting MySQL syntax error when loading the one-to-many relation of an entity

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa

I have a bidirectional one-to-many relation between this entities, all of this was created by the JPA wizard of Netbeans

Vehiculo (Vehicle)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehiculo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Vehiculo.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM Vehiculo v"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Vehiculo.findById", query = "SELECT v FROM Vehiculo v WHERE v.id =    :id")})
public class Vehiculo implements Serializable {

  //more attributes

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idVehiculo", fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<PuntoTrayecto> puntoTrayectoList;

  //methods
}
```

PuntoTrayecto (TrayectoryPoint)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "punto_trayecto")
@XmlRootElement
public class PuntoTrayecto implements Serializable {

  //more attributes

  @JoinColumn(name = "id_vehiculo", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Vehiculo idVehiculo;

}
```

I need to get a "Vehiculo" by the id, so I call the NamedQuery "Vehiculo.findById"

```
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Vehiculo.findById");
    query.setParameter("id", 1);
    Object o = query.getSingleResult();
    Vehiculo vehiculo = (Vehiculo)o;
```

I get this exception:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'precision, tiempo, velocidad, id_vehiculo FROM punto_trayecto WHERE (id_vehiculo' at line 1
```

And this is the query that is trying to call

```
Call: SELECT id, latitud, longitud, precision, tiempo, velocidad, id_vehiculo FROM punto_trayecto WHERE (id_vehiculo = ?)
```

It corresponds to the other entity "PuntoTrayecto" and I guess this SELECT query is call to fill the List puntoTrayectoList of the "Vehiculo", and the same happens if I use the JPA Controller. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by the column `precision`. This is a reserved word ([according to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)). You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa) for a workaround

Comment: I had the same problem. column name was called 'order' which is a reserved word. Thanks for this great answer