# JPA eclipse link Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, ejb-3.0, netbeans-7.2

I want to persist entity object to database that contain some null values and one of the null value is a foregin key of another table that i have to fill it later and here is the sessionbean

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package boudy.sessionbeans;

import boudy.entity.Customer;
import boudy.entity.Request;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

/**
 *
 * @author magas
 */
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class RequestBean implements RequestBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "InternetCompany-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;



    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addNewCustomer() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addNewRequest(Request requestObject) {
        try {
            userTransaction.begin();
            em.persist(requestObject);
            userTransaction.commit();
            em.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> custList = null;
        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll");
            custList = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return custList;
    }
}
```

and my Entity bean is

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package boudy.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author magas
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findById", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findBySalesdate", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.salesdate = :salesdate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByOrganizationtype", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.organizationtype = :organizationtype"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByPhone", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByGovernrate", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.governrate = :governrate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByArea", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.area = :area"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByAddress", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.address = :address"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByPackagetype", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.packagetype = :packagetype"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByPeriod", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.period = :period"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findBySpeed", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.speed = :speed"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByCost", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.cost = :cost"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByDeliveryfee", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.deliveryfee = :deliveryfee"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByRequestserial", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.requestserial = :requestserial"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByActive", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.active = :active"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByCondition", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.condition = :condition"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByReason", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.reason = :reason"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByCrddate", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.crddate = :crddate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.findByDeliverydate", query = "SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.deliverydate = :deliverydate")})
public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "salesdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date salesdate;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "organizationtype")
    private String organizationtype;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "governrate")
    private String governrate;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "area")
    private String area;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "packagetype")
    private String packagetype;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "period")
    private String period;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "speed")
    private String speed;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "cost")
    private Double cost;
    @Column(name = "deliveryfee")
    private Double deliveryfee;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "requestserial")
    private String requestserial;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Integer active;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "condition")
    private String condition;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reason;
    @Column(name = "crddate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date crddate;
    @Column(name = "deliverydate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date deliverydate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "custid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer custid;
    @JoinColumn(name = "salesid", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee salesid;
    @JoinColumn(name = "crdid", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee crdid;

    public Request() {
    }

    public Request(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getSalesdate() {
        return salesdate;
    }

    public void setSalesdate(Date salesdate) {
        this.salesdate = salesdate;
    }

    public String getOrganizationtype() {
        return organizationtype;
    }

    public void setOrganizationtype(String organizationtype) {
        this.organizationtype = organizationtype;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getGovernrate() {
        return governrate;
    }

    public void setGovernrate(String governrate) {
        this.governrate = governrate;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPackagetype() {
        return packagetype;
    }

    public void setPackagetype(String packagetype) {
        this.packagetype = packagetype;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }

    public void setPeriod(String period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(Double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public Double getDeliveryfee() {
        return deliveryfee;
    }

    public void setDeliveryfee(Double deliveryfee) {
        this.deliveryfee = deliveryfee;
    }

    public String getRequestserial() {
        return requestserial;
    }

    public void setRequestserial(String requestserial) {
        this.requestserial = requestserial;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public Date getCrddate() {
        return crddate;
    }

    public void setCrddate(Date crddate) {
        this.crddate = crddate;
    }

    public Date getDeliverydate() {
        return deliverydate;
    }

    public void setDeliverydate(Date deliverydate) {
        this.deliverydate = deliverydate;
    }

    public Customer getCustid() {
        return custid;
    }

    public void setCustid(Customer custid) {
        this.custid = custid;
    }

    public Employee getSalesid() {
        return salesid;
    }

    public void setSalesid(Employee salesid) {
        this.salesid = salesid;
    }

    public Employee getCrdid() {
        return crdid;
    }

    public void setCrdid(Employee crdid) {
        this.crdid = crdid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Request)) {
            return false;
        }
        Request other = (Request) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "boudy.entity.Request[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

and i am getting this exception

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, cost, crddate, deliverydate, deliveryfee, governrate, organizationtyp' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO request (active, address, area, condition, cost, crddate, deliverydate, deliveryfee, governrate, organizationtype, packagetype, period, phone, reason, requestserial, salesdate, speed, crdid, custid, salesid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [20 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(boudy.entity.Request[ id=1 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1415)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1505)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:208)
    at boudy.sessionbeans.RequestBean.addNewRequest(RequestBean.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.addNewRequest(Unknown Source)
    at boudy.beans.SalesRequestBean.submitAddRequestAction(SalesRequestBean.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at boudy.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, cost, crddate, deliverydate, deliveryfee, governrate, organizationtyp' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
    ... 110 more

WARNING: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Comment: Why you didn't use ContainerManagedTransaction?

Comment: to avoid getting "cannot use jta while it's in use"

Comment: You will get this error if your @Entity class has errors for columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
@Column(name = "condition")
```

with

```
@Column(name = "`condition`")
```

or, if that doesn't work,

```
@Column(name = "\"condition\"")
```

MySQL is complaining because [`CONDITION` is a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) and you must quote it if you wish to use it for a column name.  Enclosing the column name in backticks or double quotes tells JPA to escape the column name when it passes the query to the database.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463189/) goes into more detail about whether to use backticks or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I can reconfirm that if one uses a column name which happens to be a reserved word in MySQL, then one gets the exception above ("javax.ejb.EJBException...JPA eclipse link Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException"). I spent half a day trying to figure it out because I was using 'PRIMARY' (column of type Boolean; just mentioning it but it is irrelevant to/does not affect this exception ) as a column title; which is also a Reserved Word in MySQL. The error message is rather long and only after careful consideration of what "syntax error" may mean I 'got it'.