# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

Here are two entities, one is Customer and the other is Order, and one customer can obtain multiple Order, finally i return a Customer object in the controller using springmvc, but it always gave me sqlgrammer error, does jackson-bind can deal one-to-many problem?
here is the code snippet in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Customer getCustomer(){

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setRecord("Crabime");
    customer.setGender("male");
    Order order = new Order("vegitable", 12.1);
    Order order1 = new Order("fruit", 3.2);
    Set<Order> set = new HashSet<Order>();
    set.add(order);
    set.add(order1);
    customer.setOrders(set);

    customerService.save(customer);
    return customer;
}
```

and **error trace**

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
>   statement

Customer Entity

```
     @Entity
    @Table(name = "customer")
    public class Customer {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        private String record;
        private String gender;
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "customer")
        private Set<Order> orders;
        public Customer(){}
...omit setter and getter...
```

here is the Order :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
...omit setter and getter...
```

**UPDATE:**maybe it's tomcat cache problem, i remember having restarted server at that time and without anything changed, but after closing the project for few hours and reopen it, ok!

Comment: provide your DAO code, hibernate saving customer...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576236/org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarexception-could-not-execute-statement

Comment: @shantaram no there are big differences between those two question

Comment: session.save(customer) ?

Comment: @shantaram yeah,i defined it in the **CustomerService** class using Transactional annotation

Comment: what is your sql resultant? just to take a look. And your database?

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao your suggestion is right and i tried to make it clear whether generated sql grammar right or not, but i remember it's ok, although everything ok now,  maybe error caused by tomcat server cache. but seems strange

Comment: I'm glad :) if you are working with JPA TypeQuery entity is useful to write queries.

Answer (score 2):

For this error, the suggest way is add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to print the sql statement, then you can check the sql. Typical it contains the keywords, e.g. "order"

Comment: you remind me this method, but actually the sql statements are all right

Comment: @Crabime I don't think "order" is the legal name.