# JPA error in data persisting

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish-4

I have a simple table in MySQL and i want to persist data in it via JPA , but i get an error describing below, what is wrong here ?

the application is hosted in GlassFish 4, using MySQL 5 and EJB
please consider below table's definition

```
CREATE TABLE  `myproject`.`detected_issues` (
 `sdate` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `pxvalue` double NOT NULL default '0',
 `generation` varchar(6) NOT NULL ,
 `schema` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
 `node` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `parent` varchar(100) NOT NULL ,
 `layer` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
 `interval` varchar(5) NOT NULL ,
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `detected_issues_UIDX`    (`sdate`,`node`,`generation`,`schema`,`layer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and this is the entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="detected_issues")
@NamedQuery(name="DetectedIssue.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DetectedIssue d")
public class DetectedIssue implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String generation;

private String interval;

private String layer;

private String node;

private String parent;

private double pxvalue;

private String schema;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date sdate;

public DetectedIssue() {
}
}
```

with following code i get an error described at below

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ADProjectEJB")
    private EntityManager em;
DetectedIssue issuet = new DetectedIssue();
    issuet.setNode("Node");
    issuet.setParent("Parent");
    issuet.setPxvalue(0.5d);
    issuet.setGeneration("Gen");
    issuet.setSchema("HU");
    issuet.setLayer("Layer");
    issuet.setInterval("AH");
    issuet.setSdate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());      
    System.out.println(issuet.toString());
    em.persist(issuet);
    em.flush();
```

the Error

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services
>   - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INTERVAL, LAYER, NODE, PARENT, PXVALUE, SCHEMA, SDATE) VALUES
>   ('Gen', 'AH', 'Lay' at line 1 Error Code: 1064 Call: INSERT INTO
>   detected_issues (GENERATION, INTERVAL, LAYER, NODE, PARENT, PXVALUE,
>   SCHEMA, SDATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)    bind => [8 parameters
>   bound]

Comment: `interval` is a reserved word issue, needing back ticks in raw ?

Comment: you back ticked on the create but not on the insert see [pastie](http://pastie.org/10548626)

Comment: here is a better reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2224503

Comment: Tanks, backticks resolved it

Comment: or use a JPA implementation that auto-quotes keywords for you ...