# Due to syntax error table is not being created in DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

```
// USER_REGISTRATION_DB(POJO class)   
 @Entity
    @Table(name="USER_REGISTRATION_DB")
    public class UserRegistration_DB {

                 // this is for primary key
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
                @Column(name="USER-NO")
                private int userno;


        @Size(min=5, max = 5 ,message="please Enter char followed by NUM")
        @NotNull
        @Column(name="UUID")
        private String uuid;                                      

        @Size(min = 2, max = 30,message="Please Enter More than One Character")
        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")                    
        private String first_name;                      

        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME") 
        private String last_name;                          

        @NotNull(message="Please Enter Correct DOB")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/mm/yyyy")
        @Past
        @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH")
        private Date date_of_birth;                          

        //@NotNull(message="Please Enter your Customer_Id")
            @Column(name="AGE")
            private String age;                           

        //@NotEmpty(message="Please Enter your Email")
        @Size(min = 12, max = 40,message="Please Enter More than Eleven Characters")
        @Email(message="Please Enter Valid Email ID")
        @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique=true)
        private String email;                               

        //@NotNull(message="Please Enter your Password")
        @Size(min = 6, max = 30,message="Please Enter more than 6 Characters")
        @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
        private String password;                                  

        @NotNull(message="Please Enter mobile number")
        @Column(name = "MOBILE")
        private String mobile;                               

        //@NotEmpty(message="Please Enter your Username")
        @Size(min = 3, max = 40,message="Please Enter More than 2 Characters")
        @Column(name="USERNAME")
        private String username;                   

        //@NotNull(message="Please Enter your streetName")
        @Size(min = 2, max = 60,message="Please Enter More than 1 Characters")
        @Column(name="ADDRESS")
        private String address;                    

        //@NotNull(message="Please Enter your Customer_Id")
        @Column(name="V_ID")
        private String vid;    





// this my DAO class implementation

public void  saveNewUser(
            UserRegistration_DB userRegistration_DB)throws IOException
            {

            System.out.println("In User registration DB DAO class::::::::::"+userRegistration_DB.getFirst_name()+" "+userRegistration_DB.getUuid());
            Session session = getSession();                         //creating session
            session.beginTransaction();                             //begin transaction for the session.
            Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE UserRegistration_DB set first_name =:firstname,last_name =:lastname,username =:username,date_of_birth =:dob,Email =:email,password =:password,Mobile =:mobile,Address =:address,Age =:age" +
                    " Uuid =:uuid "); 

            query.setParameter("firstname",userRegistration_DB.getFirst_name());
            query.setParameter("lastname",userRegistration_DB.getLast_name());
            query.setParameter("mobile",userRegistration_DB.getMobile());
            query.setParameter("email",userRegistration_DB.getEmail());
            query.setParameter("dob",userRegistration_DB.getDate_of_birth());
            query.setParameter("age",userRegistration_DB.getAge());
            query.setParameter("password",userRegistration_DB.getPassword());
            query.setParameter("username",userRegistration_DB.getUsername());
            query.setParameter("uuid",userRegistration_DB.getUuid());
            query.setParameter("address",userRegistration_DB.getAddress());
            query.setParameter("vid",userRegistration_DB.getVid());

             int user = query.executeUpdate();

             session.save(userRegistration_DB);
             System.out.println("user values are ::::::::::::::::::"+user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();                            //here transaction complete with commit the data in db. 
            session.close();    
            //session close

    }


                // this is controller class
                //UserRegistrationController.java

@RequestMapping(value={"/signup"},method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveRegAction(@ModelAttribute("signup") @Validated UserRegistration_DB userRegistration_DB,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model,HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("the object is:" + model);
            if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            {
                logger.info("user details==========="+userRegistration_DB.getFirst_name()+""+userRegistration_DB.getLast_name()+""+userRegistration_DB.getMobile()+""+userRegistration_DB.getEmail()+""+
            userRegistration_DB.getDate_of_birth()+""+userRegistration_DB.getAge()+""+userRegistration_DB.getPassword()+""+userRegistration_DB.getUsername()+""+userRegistration_DB.getAddress());
                logger.info("Returning home.jsp page"); 
                model.addAttribute("login", new Login()); 
                model.addAttribute("user", new UserRegistration_DB()); 


                return "signup";
            }
            //registerService.saveRegister(register);  
            userRegistrationService.saveNewUser(userRegistration_DB);
            session.setAttribute("userRegistration_DB", userRegistration_DB);
            return "main";

        }



// error am getting is
// am Using Mysql DB
// User_REGISTRATION_DB is not being created
```

/* HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table USER_REGISTRATION_DB (USER-NO integer not null, ADDRESS varchar(60), AGE varchar(255), DATE_OF_BIRTH datetime not null, EMAIL varchar(40), FIRST_NAME varchar(30), LAST_NAME varchar(255), MOBILE varchar(255) not null, PASSWORD varchar(30), USERNAME varchar(40), UUID varchar(5) not null, V_ID varchar(255), primary key (USER-NO))

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-NO integer not null, ADDRESS varchar(60), AGE varchar(255), DATE_OF_BIRTH datet' at line 1   */
```

Comment: Question has nothing to jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hyphens in column names appears to be a known problem with Hibernate.

In JPA 1.0 the workaround is to escape the column name with backticks:

```
// this is for primary key
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "`USER-NO`")
private int userno;
```

In JPA 2.0 and later, you can simply place quotes around the column name, e.g.

```
@Column(name = "\"USER-NO\"")
```

**Reference:**

[**Creating field with reserved word name with JPA**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa)

Comment: General rule: avoid such names, if You can