# Hibernate 5 - naming strategy - explicit names - capital letters are ignored

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I  try to set my JPA mapping. For some reasons i have to have the same java variable / table column names (including capital letters) but i cant set the hibernate up. I tried with explicit column names:

```
@Type(type="java.lang.Integer")
@Column(name = "nextInvoiceNr")
public int nextInvoiceNr;
```

and with implicit mapping:

```
@Type(type="java.lang.Integer")
public int nextInvoiceNr;
```

Both of those methods create column name without upper letters - "nextinvoicenr".

I also tried to change hibernate configuration adding there:

```
lConf.setProperty("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl");
lConf.setProperty("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl");
```

but without success

Comment: That seems a bit weird because the last thing I did was write some code to convert the uppercase names into lower case. Do you have something around that implements `ImplicitNamingStrategy` or `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered what may be a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304319/due-to-syntax-error-table-is-not-being-created-in-db/39304404#39304404) to this one, which concerned an error stemming from using hyphens in the column name with Hibernate.  The solution there, which may be applicable here, is to escape the column name in quotes:

```
@Type(type="java.lang.Integer")
@Column(name = "\"nextInvoiceNr\"")
public int nextInvoiceNr;
```

If you are using JPA 1.0, then you can escape the column name in backticks:

```
@Column(name = "`nextInvoiceNr`")
```

Of course, the alternative to this would be to not rely on case sensitive column names.