# Using the correct dialect, PostgreSQL, on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have an entity called `User` which leads to a table called `user` which in PostgreSQL should be surrounded with quotes for it to work. I know I can specify a custom table name, but shouldn't Hibernate do the quotes automatically?

I was told that maybe Hibernate is not using the PostgreSQL dialect. Is that possible when my database is configured like this:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database_name
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
```

and if that's the case, how do I make Hibernate use the correct dialect?

I tried:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

and

```
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
```

and

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```

and

```
spring.jpa.database=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

having no effect on the error:

```
Hibernate: insert into user (created_at, last_modified_at, account_id, email, hashed_password_salt, name, over_hashed_password, preferred_name, public_key, started_displaying_sites_at, watched_tutorial_at, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2017-09-08 14:41:40.177  WARN 15764 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2017-09-08 14:41:40.177 ERROR 15764 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 13
```

Comment: Changing the dialect won't make Hibernate use quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating field with reserved word name with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is not the dialect, but the query using the reserved PostgreSQL word `user`. 
You can add the quotes through

```
@Entity(name = "`user`")
```

Or rename the `user` table.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the configuration property `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword` with value `true` to enable automatic quoting of keywords (assuming those are correctly defined in the dialect and/or JDBC database meta data).

See also [Mapping Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-mapping):

> `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword`
>   `true` or `false` (default value)
>   Specifies whether to automatically quote any names that are deemed
>   keywords.

For Spring Boot, you can set this as `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true` (thanks [Nikita Bosik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1192987/nikita-bosik))

Comment: For Spring Boot: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true`

Answer (score -1):

adding schema field in @Entity would also solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

You should put the table name on class mapping in escapes, like this:

```
@Entity(name = "\"user\"")
```

Escaping using backticks is a Hibernate specific feature; escaping with double quotes is JPA compliant.

Comment: Upvoting, because while it doesn't answer the question, it's related to the (currently) accepted answer mentioning Hibernate specific backticks. That answer doesn't answer the question as well and mentioning that backticks are Hibernate specific is of use. So no need to downvote here too much.