# How to apply @Table annotation with different names based on some Spring condition?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-annotations

## Problem: Reserved keywords

I have an entity class named `User` for historical reasons which Hibernate calculates a table name of `user` by default. That name is a reserved SQL keyword and breaks without quoting at least on Postgres, while it does work on other RDBMS like DB2i. Additionally, DB2i not only uses that unquoted name, but because it's unquoted it applies upper-case name-folding as well. This means in production some tables named `USER` already exists. While Postgres doesn't support this concrete table name without quoting, it was able to create other tables, but applies lower-case name-folding instead, so naming scheme of tables differs between RDBMS currently.

## Differently cased names vs. quoting

And this is where things become difficult: In theory the best approach si to simply quote all identifiers always, but that wasn't the case right from the start, so I now have lower- and upper-case table names, depending on RDBMS used. This means quoting the value to `user` fails on DB2i, but works on Postgres. Quoting the value to `USER` works on DB2i, but at least looks strange on Postgres because the other lower-case names.

## Conditionally use different names?

I'm aware of many other possible solutions to the problem like quoting and renaming everything, renaming the one table only to `user_account`, implement different custom naming strategies etc. But what I would like to know instead is if it's possible to apply two different `@Table` annotations to the same class, depending on some Spring property. Something like the following, only with one and the same class:

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(
  value="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect",
  havingValue = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
  matchIfMissing = true)
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User extends BusinessEntity {
```

vs.

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(
  value="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect",
  havingValue = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
  matchIfMissing = false)
@Table(name = "\"USER\"")
public class User extends BusinessEntity {
```

In the example above, the `@ConditionalOnProperty` targets the class, not the `@Table`. I would like to have the `@Table` depend on the property instead.

**So, is something like that possible somehow?**

Thanks!

Comment: SQL is case insensitive, maybe one of the RDBMS you mentioned isn't really SQL compliant

Comment: No it's not, only for unquoted names. Quoting means take names as-is and don't mangle/fold too much, e.g. keep mixed case, unquoted names instead can be handled differently by each RDBMS. But without quoting some RDBMS don't allow using reserved keywords as names, while some do. The problem is that with quoting you get use as-is, which includes support for otherwise reserved keywords. There's no way to have quoting to use reserved keywords in combination with case-folding like with unquoted names.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options which might resolve your case (all of them are actually poor cause the best option is to rename tables):

1. set `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword` to `true` as [it was suggested by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46118762/3426309)
2. take advantage of [physical naming strategies](https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5/), for example:

```java
public class ReservedWordAwareCamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy extends CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        Identifier suggested = super.toPhysicalTableName(name, jdbcEnvironment);
        Dialect dialect = jdbcEnvironment.getDialect();
        if (...) {
            return ...
        }
        return suggested;
    }

}
```

3. take advantage of [`Integrator` SPI](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator.html):

```java
public class LegacyUserTableNameIntegrator implements Integrator {

    @Override
    public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        Dialect dialect = serviceRegistry.getService(JdbcEnvironment.class).getDialect();
        for (PersistentClass persistentClass : metadata.getEntityBindings()) {
            if (persistentClass.getMappedClass() == User.class) {
                persistentClass.getRootClass().getTable().setName("...");
            }


        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: "all of them are actually poor cause the best option is to rename tables" No, the best option is using correct quoting right from the start.

As explained already, "hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true" doesn't work because of existing, differently cased tables in different RDBMS. I'm aware of the possible custom implementations for naming, that's not what my question is about.