# sql sytax error in my java code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

2017-12-26 18:35:02 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2017-12-26 18:35:02 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEAVE leave0_ where leave0_.ORGLOCATION_ID=3 and leave0_.USER_ID=3' at line 1
Dec 26, 2017 6:35:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEAVE leave0_ where leave0_.ORGLOCATION_ID=3 and leave0_.USER_ID=3' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)

Comment: Queries generally start with `SELECT`.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: I'd say a better duplicate was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/ .  The answer you link to deals with plain JDBC but the asker of this question is using Hibernate.

Comment: @LukeWoodward thanks for highlighting the issue for specific tool , I have added this one also in duplicate links