# Error when add data by JPA repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to add data to the database but when I add them I have this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, mtc_id, name, region_id) values (345, 234, 1, '123', 1)' at line 1
```

I add data by JPA repository

My repository

```
public interface StreetRepository extends JpaRepository<Street,Long> {
}
```

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/streets")
public class StreetController {

@Autowired
StreetRepository streetRepository;
@Autowired
RegionRepository regionRepository;
@Autowired
MTCRepository mtcRepository;

@RequestMapping("/get")
public List<Street> getStreets(){
    return streetRepository.findAll();
}


@PostMapping("/insert")
public Street insertStreet(@RequestBody Street street) {
    return streetRepository.save(street);
}

@RequestMapping("/update")
public Street updateStreet(@RequestBody Street street,@RequestParam("id") long id) {
    street.setId(id);
    return streetRepository.save(street);
}

@RequestMapping("/del")
public void delStreet(@RequestParam("id") int id){
    streetRepository.deleteById((long)id);
}
}
```

I used angular js (1) to add this from WEB

my script

```
this.insertToStreet = function add() {
    var name = document.getElementById("StreetName").value;
    var index = document.getElementById("StreetIndex").value;
    var channels = document.getElementById("StreetChannels").value;

    var indexRegion = document.getElementById("StreetRegion").selectedIndex;
    var region_id = 
document.getElementById("StreetRegion").options[indexRegion].value;

    var indexMTC = document.getElementById("StreetMTC").selectedIndex;
    var mtc_id = 
document.getElementById("StreetMTC").options[indexMTC].value;

    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/streets/insert',
        data: {
            name: name,
            region_id: region_id,
            index: index,
            channels: channels,
            mtc_id: mtc_id
        }
    };
    console.log(req);
    $http(req).then(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        window.location.reload();
    })
};
```

And my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "street")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Street {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "index")
private int index;

@Column(name = "channels")
private int channels;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "MTC_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Mtc mtc;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "street", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Phonenumber> phonenumbers;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "Region_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Region region;

@Column(name = "region_id")
private long region_id;

@Column(name = "mtc_id")
private long mtc_id;


public Street(String name, Region region, long region_id, long mtc_id, int index, int channels, Mtc mtc, List<Phonenumber> phonenumbers) {
    this.name = name;
    this.region = region;
    this.region_id = region_id;
    this.mtc_id = mtc_id;
    this.index = index;
    this.channels = channels;
    this.mtc = mtc;
    this.phonenumbers = phonenumbers;
}
//seters getters and empty constructor
}
```

all setters and getters are present

screen from debug (controller)

```
return streetRepository.save(street); //on this line
```

(sorry for the link, cannot add image until my reputation less than 10)

Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mv2tiaxehq2inee/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA.bmp?dl=0)

Github[here](https://github.com/lfreew1ndl/coursework)

Page = http://localhost:8080/street.html

Comment: In your `Street` class: Why do you have the region as type `Region`and additionally a `long region_id` ? You used `@JoinColumn`to let Hibernate find it automatically. Same goes for `mtc`.

Comment: I need region object to take the data and long region_id to insert in the database.  I delete @JoinColumn in Region and MTC, nothing changed

Comment: @SalimAbdul that is not true, Hibernate will automatically map the fields via the mapping annotations (e.g. `@OneToMany`). [Maybe this will help](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-using-annotations/)

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: when remove Region_id and mtc_id all work. But how add data to database from WEB?

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: You are using reserved word as column name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa

Comment: Which columns??

Comment: Ty for help ))))

Comment: Probably "index" :)