# table with column idEntity fails query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hibernate, hql

I have a table with a column named "idEntity", 
if i run this query:

```
select idEntity from algo.AUDITORIA ;
```

in oracle, there's no problem and the query runs,

but in SqlServer I'm getting:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

it seams that IDENTITY is a reserved word, and instead of refereng to the column it thinks its a function,

and if i surround idEntity with [ ] the query works:

```
select [idEntity] from algo.AUDITORIA ; -- this works!
```

my main problem is that I'm using hibernate, is there an option to tell to hibernate to force the [ ] on every name of the table columns?

Comment: The best option would be to NOT use reserved words for column names. Identity is a reserved word. Choose a better column name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating field with reserved word name with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa)

Comment: The answer on the duplicate may help, but as @SeanLange says, it's better not to use reserved words for column names.

Comment: with hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true , all the mapings in the beans HAVE to match case with the database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)