# how to map boolean fields in model class through hibernate annotations

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, naming-conventions, hibernate-mapping

how to add boolean fields in java model class through hibernate annotations.

I am doing this and its shows me error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Like bit' at line 2

My code:

```
@Column(name="Like")
private boolean like;

@Column(name="Dislike")
private boolean dislike;

@Column(name="Flag")
private boolean flag;
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get useful answers if you edit your post to include the content of the error you're seeing.

Comment: `Like` is an SQL keyword, you can't use it as column name.

Comment: ... unless you put tick marks around it, or your JPA provider does that automatically for you (seems yours doesnt have that feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact your problem is that you used  `Like` as a column name in your entity, so `Hibernate` will try to map this column to the name `Like` while it's a reserved keyword in `SQL`, that's why you got the exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Like bit' at line 2

What you can do here is either to use a different name of the column or escape the name.

For further details and escaping solutions you can check:

- [**Hibernate Tips: How to escape table and column names** article](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-escape-table-column-names/).
- **[Creating field with reserved word name with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa)**