# CONNECT BY clause required in this query block

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, connect-by

I am in the process of upgrading to Hibernate 5.3.4. This has caused some integration tests to fail. A couple of tables have columns names `id`. This is causing the `CONNECT BY clause required in this query block` error.

The methods in question are using Criteria queries. These queries are exploded into  actual sql queries which have all the column names listed in the sql query as shown in the example below.

```
SELECT
    this_.id AS id1_70_0_,
    this_.ACCT_ID AS ACCT_ID2_70_0_,
    this_.PROD_ID AS PROD_ID3_70_0_,
    this_.in_type AS in_type4_70_0_,
    this_.set_typ AS set_typ5_70_0_
FROM
    SET_TYP this_
WHERE
    this_.acct_id IN (
    SELECT
        acct_id
    FROM
        account
    START WITH
        acct_id = 630
    CONNECT BY
        PRIOR parent_acct_id = acct_id )
```

If I remove the Criteria query and use a sql query below instead it works fine.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SET_TYP
WHERE
    acct_id IN (
    SELECT
        a.acct_id
    FROM
        account a
    START WITH
        a.acct_id = 750
    CONNECT BY
        PRIOR parent_acct_id = a.acct_id )
```

How can I continue using criteria queries ?

Criteria query looks like this.

```
Criteria filter = getSession().createCriteria(SetTyp.class);
filter.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("acct_id in (select acct_id from account start with acct_id = ?0 connect by prior parent_acct_id = acct_id)", accountId, StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
Set<SettleTypeOverride> results = new TreeSet<>();
results.addAll(filter.list());
```

Comment: What is the "0" here `...start with acct_id = ?0 connect by...`?

Comment: Indexed parameter I think.

The issue may be related to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa

Trouble is when I enabled that, it causing all sorts of issues. The tests which pass without it fail now.