# EntityJavaDescriptorImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.EmbeddableJavaDescriptor

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a website. When i run my project i get this error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [FacesServlet] in context with path [/YeJayeKhoob-1.0] threw exception [The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: YeJayeKhoobPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.internal.EntityJavaDescriptorImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.EmbeddableJavaDescriptor
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.composite.EmbeddedTypeDescriptorImpl.resolveJtd(EmbeddedTypeDescriptorImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.composite.EmbeddedTypeDescriptorImpl.<init>(EmbeddedTypeDescriptorImpl.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.creation.internal.RuntimeModelDescriptorFactoryImpl.createEmbeddedTypeDescriptor(RuntimeModelDescriptorFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.makeRuntimeDescriptor(Component.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.SingularPersistentAttributeEmbedded.<init>(SingularPersistentAttributeEmbedded.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getPersistentAttributeDescriptor(Property.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.buildSingularAttribute(Property.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.makeRuntimeAttribute(Property.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractManagedType.createAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractManagedType.lambda$createAttributes$2(AbstractManagedType.java:630)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractManagedType.createAttributes(AbstractManagedType.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractManagedType.tryFinishInitialization(AbstractManagedType.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractManagedType.finishInitialization(AbstractManagedType.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractEntityTypeDescriptor.finishInitialization(AbstractEntityTypeDescriptor.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.creation.spi.RuntimeModelCreationProcess.finishInitialization(RuntimeModelCreationProcess.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.creation.spi.RuntimeModelCreationProcess.execute(RuntimeModelCreationProcess.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.creation.spi.RuntimeModelCreationProcess.execute(RuntimeModelCreationProcess.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration.scope(TypeConfiguration.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:112)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.delegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:208)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManagerRegistry.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManagerRegistry.java:125)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.proxyIfNoTx(JtaEntityManager.java:375)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createNamedQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:338)
    at com.yejayekhoob.accommodation.businesslogic.service.AccommodationTypeServiceImpl.test(AccommodationTypeServiceImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:349)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.test(Unknown Source)
    at com.yejayekhoob.accommodation.businesslogic.uimodel.HomePageMB.getWebPage(HomePageMB.java:60)
    at com.yejayekhoob.accommodation.businesslogic.uimodel.HomePageMB$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.getWebPage(com/yejayekhoob/accommodation/businesslogic/uimodel/HomePageMB.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.webbeans.el22.WrappedValueExpression.getValue(WrappedValueExpression.java:68)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I searched the internet about the error that i wrote as the title for my question, but i found nothing useful.

This is one of my entities, if helps:

```
package com.yejayekhoob.aaa.entity;

import com.yejayekhoob.common.entity.WebPage;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccessList.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AccessList a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccessList.findByUserRoleId", query = "SELECT a FROM AccessList a WHERE a.accessListPK.userRoleId = :userRoleId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccessList.findByWebPageId", query = "SELECT a FROM AccessList a WHERE a.accessListPK.webPageId = :webPageId")
})
public class AccessList implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected AccessListPK accessListPK;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userRoleId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UserRole userRole;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "webPageId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private WebPage webPage;

    public AccessList(){}

    public AccessList(final UserRole userRole, final WebPage webPage){
        this.accessListPK = new AccessListPK(userRole.getId(), webPage.getId());
        this.userRole = userRole;
        this.webPage = webPage;
    }

    public UserRole getUserRole(){
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(final UserRole userRole){
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public WebPage getWebPage(){
        return webPage;
    }

    public void setWebPage(final WebPage webPage){
        this.webPage = webPage;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (accessListPK != null ? accessListPK.hashCode() : 31);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object object){
        if(this == object){
            return true;
        }
        if( !(object instanceof AccessList) || (getClass() != object.getClass()) ){
            return false;
        }
        final AccessList other = (AccessList) object;
        return  !( 
                    ( (this.accessListPK == null) && (other.accessListPK != null) )
                    ||
                    ( (this.accessListPK !=  null) && !this.accessListPK.equals(other.accessListPK) ) 
                );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "com.yejayekhoob.aaa.entity.AccessList[ accessListPK=" + accessListPK + " ]";
    }
}


package com.yejayekhoob.aaa.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class AccessListPK implements Serializable{

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "userRoleId", nullable = false)
    private short userRoleId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "webPageId", nullable = false)
    private int webPageId;

    public AccessListPK(){}

    public AccessListPK(final short userRoleId, final int webPageId){
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
        this.webPageId = webPageId;
    }

    public short getUserRoleId(){
        return userRoleId;
    }

    public int getWebPageId(){
        return webPageId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (int) userRoleId;
        hash += (int) webPageId;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object object){
        if(this == object){
            return true;
        }
        if( !(object instanceof AccessListPK) || (getClass() != object.getClass()) ){
            return false;
        }
        final AccessListPK other = (AccessListPK) object;
        if(this.userRoleId != other.userRoleId){
            return false;
        }
        return this.webPageId == other.webPageId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "com.yejayekhoob.aaa.entity.AccessListPK[ userRoleId=" + userRoleId + ", webPageId=" + webPageId + " ]";
    }

}
```

I don't know what should i put here to help to understand my problem. Please tell me to put it here.

**Web Server : Apache TomEE Plume 8.0.0-M3**

**IDE : Apache Netbeans 11**

**Build Tool : Gradle Version v5.5.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it. I had some errors in my entities but i don't know exactly which of them cause the error, maybe all of them were guilty: **1.** One of my **entities name** and **persistent fields name** were **MySQL reserved keywords**. i corrected them with this help: [Creating field with reserved word name with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/creating-field-with-reserved-word-name-with-jpa/3463189#3463189). Thanks [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent). **2.** some of my **NamedQueries** have wrong field name in their JPQL. **3.** some **@Column** annotations have wrong values for their **name attribute**. Netbeans warned me about **1** and **2** but not **3**. I don't know maybe It should've shown me an error.