# DiscussionComment entity has Oracle reserved word as a column causing database generation error

Tags: openxava

When I try to use the stereotype DISCUSSION with Oracle I get an error because of the entity DiscussionComment column named "comment". Although I'm using the correct dialect for my Oracle version, Hibernate is not quoting DDL as needed. This is a very common problem with simple solution. I just want to apply the solution to OpenXava.

I tried to change the DiscussionComment source in OpenXava project (the one that comes with the OpenXava IDE). I changed the column name but it had no effect.

What and where should I change to alter the mapping of the entity?

The same problem applies to "YourFirstEntity", the demo entity of every project because of the "date" column.

Comment: In order the change in OpenXava code has effect you have to follow this instructions: https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/modify-openxava-code_en.html

Comment: The problem is on schema generation or when the application is running?

Comment: On schema generation. The "create table..." fails.

Comment: Did you execute schema generation from Ant, or is configured in persistence.xml so it's executed on applicaiton startup? could I see the stacktrace?

Comment: Configured in persistence.xml, executed on application startup. The output in console says the statement "create table..." failed. I just copied the output SQL to an Oracle tool and it failed too. When I changed the name of the column to "commentary" it worked.

Comment: Try to add the property hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers to true in your persistence unit in persistence.xml. If it works we could add it as a official answer here. We got the tipo from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/how-to-map-an-entity-field-whose-name-is-a-reserved-word-in-jpa

Comment: `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` actually worked. No need to make changes in the OpenXava folder and recompile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the property hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers to true in your persistence unit in persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

To modify OpenXava Java code, XML or i18n files:

- Modify the code on `OpenXava/src`, `OpenXava/xava` or `OpenXava/i18n`.
- Execute the Ant target `buildOpenXava` from
  `OpenXava/build.xml`. It compiles the OpenXava Java code and creates
  `openxava.jar`.
- Refresh OpenXava project in Eclipse (F5).
- Execute the Ant target `updateOX` from the `build.xml` of your own project.
- Refresh your own project in Eclipse (F5).

reference:
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/modify-openxava-code_en.html

Credits to @javierpaniza