# Spring database can't create entity from Model

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am learning Spring boot. I am trying to work with the Spring database. But I don't why it shows errors while creating entity from Model. I am adding my spring application properties and Model here. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private double price;
}
```

Here is my application properties file

```
# Database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=dsamgroup1
spring.datasource.password=43HJ23jlkm456ndY
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# Update schema when database changed
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

It shows the following error in console.

```
 WARN 8513 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table order (id bigint not null, price float(53) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table order (id bigint not null, price float(53) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:307) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at dsg.unibamberg.assignment1.Assignment1Application.main(Assignment1Application.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table [*]order (id bigint not null, price float(53) not null, primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table order (id bigint not null, price float(53) not null, primary key (id)) [42001-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5656) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:5616) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:5645) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:9253) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6784) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:763) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I expect this error caused by the entity name „Order“, as this is also a SQL keyword. Try adding @Table annotation on entity, using a different table name.

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords

Answer (score 1):

Order is a keyword in SQL hence the error.

Try using any other name for the table or use back ticks.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224503/6572971) for possible solutions.