# Spring Data JDBC is unable to map the column value to the property of the entity when the column name is reserved keyword

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jdbc

I'm facing a similar issue as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224503/how-to-map-an-entity-field-whose-name-is-a-reserved-word-in-jpa), but my case involves using Spring Data JDBC instead of JPA. I have an entity defined as follows:

```
@Table("TEST_TABLE")
@Data
public class TestTableEntity {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private int order;

}
```

When I call the method provided by `CrudRepository`, I encounter the error message `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'`. The generated query is:

> Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT TEST_TABLE.id AS id,
> TEST_TABLE.order AS order FROM TEST_TABLE]

To address this issue, I tried annotating the order property with `@Column("\"ORDER\"")`. This changes the generated query to:

> Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT TEST_TABLE.id AS id,
> TEST_TABLE."ORDER" AS "ORDER" FROM TEST_TABLE]

Although the error no longer occurs, the mapping of the column value to the property fails, and I always receive 0 as the value for `order`.


I also attempted to override the `getColumnName` method of the `NamingStrategy`, but it did not resolve the problem. Here's the code I used:

```
@Bean
public NamingStrategy namingStrategy() {
    return new NamingStrategy() {
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
            Assert.notNull(property, "Property must not be null.");
            return "\"" + ParsingUtils.reconcatenateCamelCase(property.getName(), "_") + "\"";
        }
    };
}
```

It appears that the issue lies with the `AS "ORDER"` clause, as it treats the double quotes as part of the column name, resulting in a failed mapping to the property.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Spring Data JDBC are you using? Spring Data JDBC does quoting of column names for a long time so this looks like the behaviour of an old version. Can you upgrade to a current version of Spring Data JDBC?

Comment: org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc:jar:2.4.6

Comment: That is rather old. You should at least update to 2.4.12 or better yet to 3.1.0.

Comment: Anyway, even that version should have quoting enabled by default. Are you configuring the JdbcMappingContext to not force quoting?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using backticks? The solution described in the linked thread?

```
@Column("`order`")
```

Alternatively for SQL Server:

```
@Column("[order]")
```

Comment: Tried backticks and it doesn't work, ``Incorrect syntax near '`'``