# SQL standard to escape column names?

Tags: sql

Is there a SQL standard to escape a column name? If not what works for MySQL and SQLite? does it also work for SQL Server?

Answer (score 106):

## Quotation Mark `"`

The [SQL:1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999) standard [specifies](https://github.com/ronsavage/SQL/blob/master/sql-99.bnf) that double quote (") ([QUOTATION MARK](https://unicode-table.com/en/0022/)) is used to delimit identifiers.

```
<delimited identifier> ::= <double quote> <delimited identifier body> <double quote>
```

Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL and SQlite all support `"` as the identifier delimiter.

They don't all use `"` as the 'default'. For example, you have to be running MySQL in [ANSI mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) and SQL Server only supports it when `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`.

Answer (score 91):

According to [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html),

- `'foo'` is an SQL string
- `"foo"` is an SQL identifier (column/table/etc)
- `[foo]` is an identifier in MS SQL
- `` `foo` `` is an identifier in MySQL

For qualified names, the syntax is: `"t"."foo"` or `[t].[foo]`, etc.

MySQL supports the standard "foo" when the `ANSI_QUOTES` option is enabled.

Comment: Note that SQLite allows `'foo'` to be interpreted as an identifier if the context wouldn't allow a string, and `"foo"` to be interpreted as a string if the context wouldn't allow an identifier, though there is a note that this behaviour may be removed in future versions.

Comment: So, how do you do "t".* ?

Comment: @thomasrutter Yeah I totally got bitten by this behavior… Tried to use `WHERE "nonexistent_column" = 0` and sqlite just happily executed it pretending that my `"nonexistent_column"` was a string.  Fully qualifying the name as `"my_table"."nonexistent_column"` forces sqlite into behaving more strictly.

Comment: `foo`, `"foo"` and `'foo'` did not work for me with MySQL. It required backticks. And to make matters worse, MySQL was providing [useless error messages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/229991/141074).

Answer (score 24):

For MySQL, use back ticks `.

For instance:

```
SELECT `column`, `column2` FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 24):

For MS SQL use `[` and `]`

```
SELECT [COLUMN], [COLUMN 2] FROM [TABLE]
```

If the column name contains a `]`, then escape it by doubling it, so a column named "Column with [brackets]" would be escaped as `[Column with [brackets]]]`.

Comment: you can have spaces in column names with ms sql!?!

Comment: you can!  I wouldn't, though.

Comment: Yes, you can have spaces or reserved words as entity names in MSSQL.  You just need to [ ] them.

Comment: BTW, if you're using [ and ] in MS SQL Server and you want to use the ] character in the name itself (for whatever reason) then you need to escape it with an other ] character (ie use ]] instead of ]).

Comment: SQL Server can be configured to use quotation marks, see the documentation for `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`.  SQL Server (and other DBMSes, like MySQL, Maria, and Oracle DB) allow identifiers to have spaces, if they're quoted.

Answer (score 6):

Putting some answers together:

MS SQL (a.k.a. T-SQL), Microsoft Access SQL, DBASE/DBF: `SELECT [COLUMN], [COLUMN2] FROM [TABLE]`

MySQL:    `` SELECT `COLUMN`, `COLUMN2` FROM `TABLE` ``

SQLite, Oracle, Postgresql: `SELECT "COLUMN", "COLUMN2" FROM "TABLE"`

Please add/edit!

Comment: For Postgres at least, you can escape double quotes that are embedded in the column name with double-double quotes, e.g. `select 3.14/6 as "A ""slice"" of pi" `  returns `A "slice" of pi` with value `0.52333`

Answer (score 2):

For DBASE/DBF use `[` and `]`

```
SELECT [DATE], [TIME], [ANY_OTHER_TO_BE_ESCAPED_COLUMN] FROM [TABLE]
```