# Very simple SQL quest

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT Id, to, Subject, Body, DateCreated, DateSent 
FROM Emails
```

Gives the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'to'.

Any idea why?

`TO` is highlighted, so I guess, it is because it thinks that is a keyword, anyway to prevent this?

Cheers.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, put `to` in brackets like this `[to]`

Comment: Or alternatively if you want to be compatible to standard ANSI SQL use double quotes: "to"

Comment: You can also not pick such inane words to be field names.

Answer (score 0):

You escape it by surrounding it with `[]` (SQL Server specific):

```
SELECT Id,[to],Subject,Body,DateCreated,DateSent 
FROM Emails
```

You can also use the standard SQL escape, `"` as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names):

```
SELECT Id,"to",Subject,Body,DateCreated,DateSent 
FROM Emails
```