# Backticks on fieldnames in a MySQL UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: Query without backticks.]

[image: Query with backticks]

I'm not exactly sure if I should or shouldnt using backticks since ORDER is a reserved word in PHP.

Anyone have any clue how I can get this to work?

CODE:

```
UPDATE models SET firstname='322', lastname='322', email='322', password='322', `group`='322', phone='322', timeofday='322', dayofweek='322', address='322', city='322', state='322', zip='322', gender='322', hair='322', eye='322', birthday='322', birthmonth='322', birthyear='322', bustshirt='322', cup='322', waist='322', hips='322', weight='322', inches='322', dressjacket='322', workxp='322', twitter='322', facebook='322', joindate='322', instagram='322', imdb='322', parentid='322', ethnicity='322', error='' WHERE id='322'
```

Comment: `error=` is okay, I fixed that after I uploaded these pictures. It still gives an error with it `error=''`

Comment: Please post that as text.

Comment: For a standard way to escape identifiers, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2901453. Backticks are rather unique to MySQL. And the validator is probably trying to remain platform-agnostic, so it doesn't accept them.

Comment: I doubt all those columns are varchar,post the schema.