# Why can't I "SELECT INTO" a database whose name starts with a number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
Main.dbName = "7202" 

query = "select * into " + Main.dbName + ".dbo.[AccountReceivableHistory]
        from " + dbOrigin + ".dbo.[AccountReceivableHistory] where
        AccountReceivableHistory].Date >= '2012-12-27' and    
        AccountReceivableHistory].Date < '2012-12-28'"
```

The error says

> Syntax error near '7202'.

Comment: Prefixing a `schema.table` combination with another identifier serves as a database name. You have a database called `7202`?

Comment: Starting database object names using numbers is bad practice. You are forcing quotation by that using "" or []. Why not put a simple prefix to it like TBL_7202?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a number for a table name (or database name, or schema name - see my comment), however, you will need to escape it with `[]`:

```
select *
into [123].[456].[789] 
from OtherTable;
```

Where `[123]` represents database, `[456]` represents schema and `[789]` represents a table.

**Edit**

In the interests of [standardisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901499/314291), e.g. if there is a chance of future portability between RDBMS, note that preference should be given to use double quotes `"` instead of `[]` for escaping, e.g.

```
SELECT * from "123"."456"."789";
```

You will however need to ensure that `set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` is set on the connection.

If the names of objects are being constructed dynamically, note that it is also possible to override the default escaping of the [`QUOTENAME` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx?f=255) by providing a character delimiter as the second parameter, e.g.:

```
select QUOTENAME('123', '"');
```