# Mysql select always returns empty set

Tags: mysql

So for some reason my Mysql table always returns an empty set

```
mysql> show table status like 'test_table';
+-----------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name            | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free  | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-----------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test_table      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 1625218 |            749 |  1218363392 |               0 |            0 | 1234173952 |           NULL | 2015-07-25 12:03:40 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-----------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_table;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Any advice on how I can debug this?

Here's the create table

```
| test_table | CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `export_date` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `recommended_age` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `artist_name` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `seller_name` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_url` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `support_url` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `view_url` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `artwork_url_large` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `artwork_url_small` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `release_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: have you tried putting the the table name into quotes? maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901502/5127499

Comment: @BK435 Added the show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an import problem. I imported my data with a Python script and didn't have autocommit set to true (the script was written for an older version of MYSQL)

Comment: I was helping a friend fix his code and he didn't tell me that either

Answer (score 0):

Its possibly the mySQL server does not know which database you are searching and is defaulting to the default schema where the table doesnt exist?

Try using the USE verb with your database name.
eg: if your database was named db1 and your table was mytable.

USE db1;

SELECT * FROM mytable;

# selects from db1.mytable

Comment: Tried this as well and didn't make a difference :(

Comment: Long shot guess.. select * from test_table where 1;

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your data is not flush properly in to the table, run flush table by the following command and then check again.

```
FLUSH TABLES;
```

Comment: how you insert the data ?