# mariadb select * returns empty set

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

when I run `SELECT * FROM urlcheck`
it returns 'EMPTY Set (0.0 sec)'
According `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'urlcheck'`
The table has 3 rows.
Table structure is:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+<br>
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |<br>
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+<br>
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |<br>
| coursegroup | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |<br>
| url         | varchar(2588) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |<br>
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+<br>
```

I start by selecting the database with `USE db`
any ideas why this happened. I know this is similiar to [Mysql select always returns empty set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632895/mysql-select-always-returns-empty-set)[Mysql select always returns empty set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632895/mysql-select-always-returns-empty-set) but that was apparently a corrupted database. I have truncated this database and add new rows and I still get the same problem. The code that adds records FWIW is

```
cur.execute('insert into urlcheck (coursegroup, url) values("'+coursegroup+'","'+url+'");')
db.commit
cur.close
```

Comment: Well, your table **is** empty, so you need to check your insert code.

Comment: you should always make the effort and enter an errror handling to your code. Besides using prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a syntax error in my code. 
should have been:
`db.commit()`
`cur.close()`

lack of parentheses caused the code not to write. I leave this here even as it redounds to my own humiliation in the hopes it helps someone else.