# Data inputed is not going to sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
else{

    PreparedStatement ps1;
    String query= "INSERT INTO 'registration'('u_fname','u_lname','u_uname','u_pass',u_address')VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

   try{
       ps1=MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        ps1.setString(1, fname);
        ps1.setString(2, lname);
        ps1.setString(3, uname);
        ps1.setString(4, pass);
        ps1.setString(5, address);

        if(ps1.executeUpdate() > 0)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"New User Added");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }}
```

generates this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1415)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1782)
    at newpackage.RegisterForm.jButtonRegisterActionPerformed(RegisterForm.java:402)
    at newpackage.RegisterForm.access$400(RegisterForm.java:22)
    at newpackage.RegisterForm$5.actionPerformed(RegisterForm.java:162)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Change your `'` to `\`` characters.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There is no need for backticks here, and anyway that would only work on MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It also works in Hive (which is what I've been using lately). It *looked* like that was what [OP wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is really just a typo, but I am posting an answer because the train of thought which might have led you to typo is worth discussing.  Here is your corrected query string:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO registration (u_fname, u_lname, u_uname, u_pass, u_address) ";
sql += "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
```

By placing the column names into single quotes, you were effectively telling the database that you want to pass in string literals as column names.  Instead, you want to just use the column names themselves, unescaped in any way.