# Mysql BETWEEN request returns empty row

Tags: sql, datetime, between

I have an entry like that in my postgreSql DB :

[image]

and used this sql request :

```
SELECT *
FROM "options"
```

WHERE 'startDate' >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000+00' AND 'startDate' <= '2021-05-31 00:00:00.000+00';

That should return me the entry but it doesn't :(

I tried this request :

```
SELECT *
FROM "options"
WHERE 'startDate' BETWEEN '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000+00' AND '2021-05-31 00:00:00.000+00';
```

Returns an empty row.

I also made few tests with those request :

```
SELECT * FROM "options" WHERE 'startDate' > '2021-05-31';
```

and this returns the entry (it shouldn't because 'startDate' is 2021-05-04... I also replaced 2021 by 2022/2030, no matter what date in the futur, it's returning the entry...

So guys please help!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should not quote you column and table names? try something like
``SELECT * FROM options WHERE startDate >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000+00' AND startDate <= '2021-05-31 00:00:00.000+00';``

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: `'startDate' >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00.000+00'` compares the **string** `'startDate'` with the string `'2021-05-01 00:00:00.000+00'` which is always true because the character `s` is bigger than the character `2`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bc102972e13ca95c6298218a617bf0ae

Comment: Do not wrap column names in single quotes.  I consider this a typo and am voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help and attention!
It's working now, I had just to use double quotes for my startDate field like so :

`SELECT * FROM "options" WHERE "startDate" >= '2021-05-01' AND "startDate" <= '2021-05-31'`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string to a string.
Try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM options WHERE startDate > '2021-05-31';
```

If above does not work, try using double quotes around column names.

```sql
SELECT * FROM options WHERE "startDate" > '2021-05-31';
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cdeaaf19845d51ea227ac18ed454857a

More info "why": https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901499/1727039

Comment: Hey Mr.P thanks for your reply!

In fact, this was my first test :

`const lastMonthFirstDate = moment().subtract(1,'months').startOf('month').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
SELECT * FROM "options" WHERE 'startDate' >= '${lastMonthFirstDate}'`

that returns me the entry, but it returns the entry even if I use this request with a date from futur :

SELECT * FROM "options" WHERE 'startDate' > '2023-05-31';

That returns me the entry too :/

Comment: In the comment you are still comparing strings. Omit the quotes. Take a look at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=239df2b4470e66ccb4af63bbab912e57