# Schema has escaped quotation marks in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First part of my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_09_25_175429) do
  create_table "book", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "genre"
    t.index "\"tags\"", name: "index_formulas_on_tags"
  end
```

As you can see, tags has escaped quotes in it. How do I fix this, and how did this happen in the first place? Actually, I'm now considering that this could be intentional, but I could of doubt it?

Comment: What kind of RDBMS is it?

Comment: SQLite3? I think?

Comment: try and dump the schema straight from the RDBMS, you have some entity in there with actual double-quotes in the naming.....

Comment: For example I can do this '   create table "X" (....) '

Comment: That creates a table with name DOUBLE QUOTE X DOUBLE QUOTE....

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names

Comment: There should be a rails way of doing what I want