# How can I login using ASP .NET Web application(Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to insert login but after I enter the username and password, using ASP .NET the error said

Server Error in '/' Application.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Source Error:

Line 45:
Line 46:                     connection.Open();
Line 47:                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MY CODE IN LOGIN BUTTON IS

protected void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        string conn= @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Table (username, password) VALUES (@username, @password)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", unametxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordtxt.Text);

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            
        }

        unametxt.Text = "";

    }
```

I tried to search and asking in chat gpt, I follow their instruction but suddenly, I still get error,
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE stackoverflow peeps

Comment: `Table` is a reserved word in SQL. Are you sure that your table was named "Table"?

Comment: yesss @Yong Shun

Comment: Best to test all queries using SQL Server Management Studio where the error messages are much better than in c#.  You can also check the log files in SSMS in the explorer under Management.

Comment: Either you should rename your table name (Using `TABLE` as table name is really poor, you should name it with a meaningful name) or you need to escape the table name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901502/8017690. Would say rename it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL standard to escape column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Table` is a reserved keyword in SQL, and you should avoid using it as a table name. If your table is actually named `Table`, you should consider renaming it to something else that is not a reserved keyword or put your table name in square brackets [ ] like `INSERT INTO [Table] (username, password) VALUES (@username, @password)`.