# how do I query a column that has a name similar to a reserved word?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with SQL column names that look like SQL keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords)

```
SELECT thing.Column FROM mytable thing
```

When I run this, SQL Server says that I have "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Column'

Comment: quick fix is to use `[` and `]` around the column name, but the **real solution** is to not use reserved words and change the column name to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the column name in square brackets, thusly:

```
SELECT thing.[Column] FROM mytable thing
```

You can also use double-quotes (I believe this is the more standard SQL syntax):

```
SELECT thing."Column" FROM mytable thing
```

Note that double-quotes only work when QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is on, however it is on by default.

Here is the [MSDN reference on delimited identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT [thing].[Column] FROM [mytable] AS [thing]
```

Keep trying to use those brackets every time, cause You never know when Your system will migrate to a newer version and if the new one hasn't got new set of reserved words.