# SQL query "OBJECT" problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table which contains filed name as OBJECT.
I am trying to fetch records from the table using select query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE OBJECT = "11";
```

I am getting the following error - `INVALID COLUMN NAME`.
Looks like its reading OBJECT as SQL KEYWORD and not as table field name.

I am writing this query in sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select * from table1 where [OBJECT] = '11';
```

[MSDN: Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx)

Btw, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords) is another SO-question to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose keywords in brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [OBJECT] = '11'
```

Comment: But don't enclose values in double quotes, use single quotes.

Comment: You're right @Johan. I was just copied his original query without double-checking. I edited my answer to use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotation marks. But if object is numeric, don't use any quotation marks around the number 11.

```
             where mycol = 'x'  

             not 

           where mycol = "x"
```

Comment: Thanks.. I realized the problem.