# how do you insert to a column name that is similar to an SQL statement? in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a column name called "condition", and I don't know if this is an SQL statement but its in color pink in my phpmyadmin sql. so how do you insert to a column that shares the same name to an SQL statement. I could just change it to another variable but this idea have me intrigued. I tried this:

[How to deal with SQL column names that look like SQL keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords)

but it only works for select statements.

So does anyone have an idea how to do this using Insert, Update, and Delete?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words are called [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and in MySQL you will need to escape them using backticks:

```
insert into yourtable (`condition`)
select yourValue
from yourOtherTable;
```

My suggestion would be to stay away from using these words for tables and columns.

Comment: Backtick = left of the '1' key, in case you don't use it often.

Comment: left of 'z' on Mac! ;)

Comment: or left of backspace with german layout. but i guess we should stop this ;)

Comment: @MarcoForberg we'll never know when we'll be using a foreign keyboard so might as well continue lol

Comment: ALT+'9' then '6'  universal backtick?

Comment: Num9 and Num6 would be more precise ;)

Answer (score 1):

In mySQL you can use

```
`condition`
```

instead of

```
[condition]
```

of mssql