# How to use sql reserve keyword in column name

Tags: sql-server, reserved-words

How to use an SQL reserved keyword like the column name "desc" in a select statement?

```
select "desc" from tablename
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with SQL column names that look like SQL keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords)

Comment: You better consider not using reserved names as user defined object names...

Comment: 30 seconds of [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=sql+how+to+use+reserved+words+in+a+statement&oq=sql+how+to+use+reserved+words+in+a+statement) would have gotten you all of these answers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use brackets

```
select [desc] from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Standard, you can use [delimited identifiers](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_renaming_columns_calculations_in_result_set/page2.html) in this case, ex.

```
create table Tdesc("desc" int);
go
select "desc" from Tdesc order by "desc" desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

back quotes worked for me in Hive SQL: I have a column named from, so:

```
select `from` from myTable;
```