# How to select the reserved word (limit) in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql-9.1

I have the field 'limit' in a table in my postgres database. I run psql and I can't select, update, change this field because is a reserved word in postgresql. There is a way to manage this field?

```
serene-retreat::SILVER=> select limit from companies;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "limit"
LINE 1: select limit from companies;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL reserved (key)words need to be quoted using double quotes:

```
select "limit" 
from companies;
```

Note that this also makes column case-sensitive: `"LIMIT"` is a different name than `"limit"`.

This all explained in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
select [limit] from companies;
```

or

```
select companies.[limit] from companies;
```

Comment: this can also be tried...    select '`limit`' from companies;

Comment: I dont understand your last suggestion

Comment: It list the word 'limit' and no values and the header say '?column?'

Comment: That does not work "in SQL". The SQL standard is pretty clear: reserved words need to be enclosed in double quotes. Square brackets are completely invalid "in SQL" (the standard query language) for an identifier

Comment: check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords

Comment: That's for *SQL **Server*** not for "SQL". (you _can_ actually make SQL Server honour the SQL standard and accept double quotes for quoted identifiers)