# Query a database with SQL using a reserved word through R

Tags: r

I'm using R to analyze a table that I first query with SQL

The problem is the table (schema) name is a reserved word.

The following query results in error:

```
# Establish connection
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "myDb")

# Write SQL query
query <- 'SELECT * FROM "GENERIC".table1 WHERE column1 = "RandomText"'

# Pull data
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, query)

ERROR: column "RandomText" does not exist;
```

RandomText isn't a column to begin with. It seems as if I can't use the quotes twice, but it is required to pass the query as a string to DBI function.

How can I query SQL in R when the table has a reserved name in it?

The link below did not help me solve the issue in R

[Similar question addressing the same issue in Postgres directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053168/how-to-select-the-reserved-word-limit-in-postgres)

I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question - using an escape character (\) and switching quote characters worked:

```
# Write SQL query
query <- "SELECT * FROM \"GENERIC\".table1 WHERE column2 = 'RandomText'"
```