# How to drop the column name which contain dot

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using `SQL server 2008`

column name is : `file.retry`

I want to drop the column `file.retry.` while running the below query getting the exception

```
ALTER TABLE FILEQ DROP COLUMN file.retry

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

How to solve this issue. Any one can help please

Comment: I found this, which seems like it answers your problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/is-it-okay-to-put-dots-in-sql-server-database-names
Try wrapping the table name in brackets [ ]

Comment: There's a basic recommendation to avoid any name which needs to be enclosed in brackets (or Standard SQL's double quotes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SQL column names that look like SQL keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords)

Answer (score 8):

Surround `file.retry` in square brackets like so `[file.retry]` to avoid the interpreter trying to parse it as a *table.column* identifier.

`ALTER TABLE FILEQ DROP COLUMN [file.retry]`

Answer (score 2):

Use square brackets around  the column name

```
ALTER TABLE FILEQ DROP COLUMN [file.retry]
```