# How to query a column named "OR" in BigQuery?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

We unfortunately have a table with a column that has been written with the field name  of "OR".

If we try to query this table - "SELECT OR FROM etc." we get an error because OR is a reserved word.

How do we query that column using BigQuery's legacy SQL queries?  (We need that column and not others.)

We thought we could use "SELECT *" and BigQuery's "exclude" feature but isn't part of legacy SQL so we are unable to use it. Other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue when querying the Hacker News dataset. It appears the authors added a "by" column [because they were replicating the API response keys](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10441409). However, it's difficult to query and [not best practice in database design](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10441325).

I tried the brackets:

```
SELECT
   [by] as author_name
FROM
   `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full`
LIMIT
   1000
```

but received the following error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword BY at [2:4]
```

Here is a query that works on the Hacker News dataset in BigQuery with Standard SQL Dialect:

```
SELECT
  b.by as author_name
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` as b
LIMIT
  1000
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that you're looking for an answer using legacy SQL (and you found one using the bracket syntax), but for future readers, `or`, `and`, etc. are valid column names for query results in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/). The following query will not return an error, for instance:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS `or`,
    2 AS `and`
)
SELECT * FROM T;
```

Answer (score 0):

We found [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords) for this - except you need to do something additional to what they describe. You cannot just add brackets to the name - you also need to give it a new column name.

The answer is to query like this:

```
SELECT [OR] AS new_column_name FROM ...
```