# ERROR 1064 (42000) - can't find the mistake in the SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've table named `networks`:

```
mysql> describe networks;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| range | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to `INSERT` value in this table with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO networks(range) VALUES("10.10.10.10/24");
```

However I get this error:

> **ERROR 1064 (42000):** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range) VALUES("10.10.10.10/24")' at line 1

I tried playing with the quotes (changing them form " to ', and similar stuff), however it didn't work. Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-R

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords

Comment: The source of the problem is `range`; it is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Back Ticks:

```
INSERT INTO networks(`range`) VALUES('10.10.10.10/23');
```

This may help.

Comment: The same error:
mysql> INSERT INTO networks(range) VALUES('10.10.10.10/23');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range
) VALUES('10.10.10.10/23')' at line 1

Comment: As the error message clearly says, the problem is at or before `range`. Both single and double quotes can be equally used to enclose strings.

Comment: Yes, @iamsankalp89. You have to use `back ticks' instead of 'quotes'

Comment: Ok seems you all correct, I will delete it no issue thanks for help –

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `networks` (`range`) VALUES ('10.10.10.10/24');
```

You can enclose table and column names into backticks to avoid conflicts with reserved words on MySQL. In your case `RANGE` is a reserved word and can't be used as a column or table name without backticks. A string value should be enclosed in single-quotes.

> **Note:** You should avoid using reserved words like `RANGE` as column and table definition. You can find a list of all reserved words on the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Or, better, avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers.

Comment: may be, your answer is better