# Import CSV to SQL Express using Python

Tags: python, sql, csv

I'm trying to take a csv file and import it into sql server express using Python. I've googled the problem and the solution I'm seeing that seems to be working for everyone else is:

```
import pymssql
import csv
conn = pymssql.connect(
    server="servername",
    user='username',
    password='password',
    database='db'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
with open('new_csv_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader) 
    query = 'insert into MyTable({0}) values ({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for data in reader:
        values = map((lambda x: x.strip()), data)  # No need for the quote
        print(tuple(values))
        cursor.execute(query, tuple(values))
    cursor.commit()
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
conn.close()
```

I've confirmed the code works it's just the "execute()" part doesn't. 
query is ok, but "values" is giving me the following error:

```
(102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'Year'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Where 'Year' is the column I'm trying to fit the data in.

Thanks.

Comment: can you print `query` before execute it?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a work-around using sqlalchemy and pandas

```
import sqlalchemy

print('Creating Engine')
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password@localhost/db')
print('Reading Table')
df = pd.read_sql_table("table_name",engine)
print(df)
df_new = pd.read_csv('table_name_new.csv'%)
df_new.to_sql(name="table_name",
          con = engine,
          if_exists='replace'         
        )
df_test = pd.read_sql_table("table_name",engine)
```

If someone did find out why my code doesn't work I'm still interested. I don't know if it's a Python 3 issue (I'm using Python 3).

Cheers

Comment: There's a function [YEAR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in T-SQL. When you pass 'Year' as a literal in your query string, the server probably interprets that as an attempted function invokation.  It should work if you [escape the column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords) in the query string: `",".join(map(lambda x: "[{}]".format(x), columns))`. It's just a hunch, though; I can't test this myself.